# Why Doesn't the User "Community" Have a More Personal Name?

Tags: discussion, community-user

Why doesn't the user [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) have a catchier name?  "Community" seems a bit bland, not to mention a bit confusing.

The user Community is a big part of SO. I think this is long overdue.

**The name can be voted on by the community.**

**Note:** *I am aware that there are two separate Community users, one for Stack Overflow and the other for Meta Stack Overflow*

Thoughts?

Comment: Community is very sad that you don't like it's name.

Comment: _"one for StackOverflow and the other for Meta StackOverflow"_ Actually, I would assume it's the same user. After all, having an account on SO main gives you an attached account on Meta... So I'd say they're the same account. In fact, if you look, there are meta posts attached to the profile on main.

Comment: @Kendra This is the one for SO http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community - and this is the one for Meta SO http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

Comment: @ILoveCSS "So are you a different user here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7234396/i-love-css than on the main site: http://stackoverflow.com/users/7234396/i-love-css "?! The community user is just one user, same user id.

Comment: @Rizier123 SO Community - Member for 8 years, 5 months / Meta SO Community - Member for 2 years, 8 months

Comment: And anyways, it may very well be the case that it's the same user. That's besides the main point.

Comment: @ILoveCSS If you are confused about that, then probably because there was a split 2 years ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888

Comment: The userId is the same. Your meta account isn't officially "created" until you actually come to meta, AFAIK. (Or it may be a result of the split) Your meta account is still tied to your main, by the userId, and so is Community's.

Comment: What type of username would be more personal for a "collective entity?"

Comment: "jQuery" of course.

Comment: @ILoveCSS BTW don't get scared from the votes here. [Voting is different on meta.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: What Is Up With Those Capitals In The Title?

Comment: [Stack Exchange Bob](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Bob)?

Comment: You win! @MartinSmith

Comment: It should be a sock puppet, of course.

Comment: @rene That's Called [Title Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Stylistic_or_specialised_usage), Je Weet Toch? I dislike it with passion as well. It's Not that Titles Become More Readable With it, But It's a Matter of Style.

Comment: While voting is different on Meta, showing research/effort is expected here too. If you have proposal for different name - suggest one. In current state seem to be very pointless post...

Comment: @Glorfindel Ughh, that is ugly and it is even inconsistent. But obviously it is a thing and asking to get that normalized is probably not going to fly....

Comment: *not to mention a bit confusing* - How would a catchy or personal name be any less confusing?

Comment: Code markup is for material that's to be interpreted by a computer program. The username "Community" is not in that category. Sardonic remarks about the votes your post is getting have no place in that post.

Comment: I propose the new name be: "Community" ... notice the subtle difference there.

Comment: Community isn't a person, why should it have a personal name?

Comment: We live in a time where people name their kids after fruits and celestial bodies, 'Community' by today's standards is just as personal as any other  :)

Answer (score 7):

I propose we form a committee to find a better name. This committee should have at least 30 well-respected community members and 5 Stack Exchange employees (although we should probably have a meta discussion about that first, just to make sure we all agree on those numbers). The whole community should be able to vote who gets on the committee just like we can vote for moderators. The chairman of the committee should also be voted upon.

After this committee has been installed, they will investigate alternative names using the best available scientific evidence taking into account such factors such as pronounce-ability, ease of spelling, possible offensive references in various languages/cultures, how well it integrates with the graphic layout, whether the name conflicts with other "bot" users from other sites, the aesthetics of the name, and other important factors.

After the committee presents its comprehensive report, the Stack Exchange network community should be able to vote on the name it wants. This, of course, will be preceded by a meta discussion on the most applicable voting methodology (we might have to form another committee for that, there are some important decisions to be made here as well) after which one or more rounds of network-wide voting for the new name is chosen.

It is of course critical that we have several discussions on this important vote, so perhaps we should set up a round of meta questions to that those in favour (or against) a particular name are allowed to make their case.

After the votes are counted, the Stack Exchange team will change absolutely nothing, because it turned out the entire thing is a gigantic [bikeshed](http://bikeshed.com/) and waste of time. Who'd have thunk it?

Comment: Can we have a conference call to determine the wording for the meta post about the numbers for the committee?

Comment: @TinyGiant Why not a community symposium in New York City?

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately I would not be able to attend.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, we should change it to "SO Mega Robot" or something.

Of course, we would need to run that past the **Community** Managers, the Director of **Community** development, the **Community** Growth Operations Specialist - basically the whole of the **Community** team would need to agree with the change.

Also we would probably need to get the **Community** (us) to vote on it too.

But why stop there? "community" is so 2016 anyways. We could all be "SO Mega Robots" and the community team could be "SO Mega Robot Managers" etc...

***BRING ON THE STACK OVERFLOW MEGA ROBOTS!!!***

---

Okay, a bit over the top - but the point I'm trying to make is that there a  constant theme of "community" around Stack Overflow, and not just here - all the other sites on the Stack Exchange network too. If we change it in *one* place then surely *that's* more confusing, no?

---

<sup>*P.S. Don't take this personally, I'm just "yankin' your chain" ;)*</sup>

Comment: Mega Robot? That's still a description, not a real name. I vote for Megatron. Of course Optimus Prime would be the more logical choice under normal circumstances, but the last thing SO needs is more Autobots.