# 2016: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

This came up in an internal discussion with some Stack Overflow moderators earlier today: even those of you who are pretty familiar with how this site works often have no idea how often various actions are performed.

I've previously tried to address this with [a report on deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why) and [a tool for analyzing closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257449/new-10k-tool-question-close-statistics)... But there's a lot more to moderation than closing and deletion. And... [There's an awful lot of moderation that *isn't done by moderators*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling).

So with that in mind, here's a birds-eye view into what actually happened on Stack Overflow moderation-wise last year, for your collective edification and bemusement:

```
Action                                  Moderators  Community¹ 
--------------------------------------- ----------  ----------
Users suspended²                            2,256        1,421  
Users destroyed                             8,680            0  
Users deleted                               4,855            0  
Users contacted                             6,122            0  
User suspensions lifted early                  57            0  
User review-bans lifted early                  62            0  
User banned from review                       922        6,467  
Tasks reviewed³: Triage queue                 138    2,212,710  
Tasks reviewed: Suggested Edit queue        1,378    1,864,076  
Tasks reviewed: Reopen Vote queue              69      206,100  
Tasks reviewed: Low Quality Posts queue       774      758,627  
Tasks reviewed: Late Answer queue              16      329,306  
Tasks reviewed: Helper queue                    0       45,984  
Tasks reviewed: First Post queue               37      869,376  
Tasks reviewed: Close Votes queue           2,176      581,204  
Tags merged                                   124            0  
Tag synonyms proposed                          96          247  
Tag synonyms created                          126           80  
Tag highlight language set                     37            0  
Revisions redacted                            554            0  
Questions unprotected                          14          308  
Questions reopened                          1,315        9,374  
Questions protected                            94        4,891  
Questions migrated                          1,217          988  
Questions merged                               97            0  
Questions flagged⁴                          1,762      675,987  
Questions closed                           23,241      336,496  
Question flags handled⁴                    52,153      625,596  
Posts unlocked                                133          755  
Posts undeleted                             2,095       79,976  
Posts locked                                  342       12,009  
Posts deleted⁵                            131,129    1,322,907  
Posts bumped                                    0       22,856  
Escalations to the CM team                    925            0  
Comments undeleted                          1,038            0  
Comments flagged                            2,735      238,966  
Comments deleted⁶                         257,297      923,585  
Comment flags handled                     204,572       37,129  
Bounties canceled                             230            0  
Answers flagged                             4,776      423,115  
Answer flags handled                      273,000      154,891  
All comments on a post moved to chat          208            0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the vast membership of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise [affectionately referred to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340791/why-doesnt-the-user-community-have-a-more-personal-name) as [user #-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores a good chunk of deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action. For a complete treatment of post deletion on Stack Overflow, see: [What posts get deleted, and why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why)

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Comment: We didn't make 10k users destroyed? Those trolls aren't working hard enough.

Comment: Looks like the mods need to step up their review queue count...

Comment: @Steve: Mods have more than enough on their plates with the flag queue.

Comment: @JonEricson maybe I should have added /s. Of course the mods do great work.

Comment: Under what circumstances bounties are cancelled?

Comment: [Some discussion here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281265/let-moderators-immediately-end-not-refund-bounties) @Vivek

Comment: Thanks, @Shog9. These are very interesting stats.

Comment: @Shog9 I'd be interested in stats about how many questions/answers were destroyed by 6 community flags as spam/offensive. The "posts locked by community" number gives a ballpark but I understand it includes moderator binding spam flags and rejected migrations.

Comment: Regarding the *Comments undeleted* number, you might want to mention that most of this probably stems from a moderator deleting all comments on a post and then undeleting the few worth staying.

Comment: I'm looking at the `Answer flags handled 273,000 154,891` values. It looks like the moderators handle more of these than the community. Can we do something to get the balance correct there? (Increasing the number of reviews a user can do or decreasing the number of reviews needed to do away with the post).

Comment: Wow. I never knew that Triage is by far the most active queue.

Comment: @dorukayhan probably because it's the first queue one can enter. After a few hundred reviews in those you get disillusioned and don't enter the other queues at all.

Comment: This really makes me wonder if we need to lower the rep threshold for the CVQ.  1.8 million reviews were done in the SEQ by 2K+ users but only 600K 3K+ rep users decided to do CVQ reviews.

Comment: In addition to what @NathanOliver said, it'd be great to have more CVs for the queue separately. I tend to spent my CVs during the day on posts I encounter, having not many left for the queue late in the day.

Comment: Can we have stats for individual moderators?

Comment: @RamenChef, would that really be relevant or interesting? It's not like moderation was a competition.

Comment: what's the difference between a post and an answer?

Comment: @Cœur, `Answer extends Post`.

Comment: @BhargavRao But how often do moderators handle an answer flag before the community even has a chance to do so? In general, the queue size for answers is fairly low (only close votes has a huge backlog), so I don't think you can just conclude "the community needs to handle more answer flags" here. Perhaps a better question here is "why are moderators handling so many answer flags and not closing more questions?" Only 23k posts were closed by mods (vs. 336k by community). Closing questions would *also* pre-emptively handle answer flags since bad questions tend to get bad answers.

Comment: @NathanOliver don't forget those figures are also skewed by the fact that there will be more 2k+ users than 3k+ users on the site.

Comment: @MacroMan Oh I know about that.  What would be cool to know is how many of the suggested edit reviews were done by 3k+ users.  If it is a high percentage then at least we know people just do not like to close things instead of people not having enough rep to close things.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes I agree it would be good to see a more detailed breakdown between the rep rankings

Comment: @RamenChef - Moderators have an internal dashboard that shows flags handled, posts deleted, etc. per moderator. We all know who's handling the most flags, but turning this into a competition isn't going to help moderation quality. You could handle 20 comment flags in the time it takes to handle one flag on a massive spam operation, but which task is more important to take care of? Numbers don't tell the whole story.

Comment: Would it be possible to get stats like this for other sites in the network?

Comment: Wow, talk about mods slacking off on the review queues! I say we light a fire under them until they complete at least 1,000 reviews a day! (Oopsy, forgot about weekends. Make that 1,400 reviews a day.)

Comment: @Aaroninus You do realize that the primary job of the moderators is not to work in the review queues, right?

Comment: @bluefeet I forgot to add the :P

Comment: @Aaroninus Mods are neither expected or required to even *look* at the review queues. That's for any regular user with >500 rep. So really, this one's on you. Rep up and hit the queues, slacker!

Comment: What is the difference between a deleted user and a destroyed user?

Comment: @BrianRogers deleted only deletes the uid information, destroyed removes any action done on the site.

Comment: @BhargavRao That's based on the assumption that there's an equal number of answer flags that non-mods _can_ handle. I would guess that many of these are custom flags which we never see. Also consider that NAA reviews sometimes result in the post being handed off to mods _after_ it's been reviewed.

Comment: @BhargavRao: I also think that the *Answer flags handled* stat encompasses *all* flags on answer posts, not just NAA and VLQ flags. The community can't help with all of those.

Comment: @MartijnPieters still a relationship 1.5:1 seems worth looking at more closely.

Comment: @Braiam: There are loads of stats with a infinity:0 relationship, why are answer flags special here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've always been told that moderators were exception handlers... and if exceptions are more than the common problems, we are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Braiam: a ratio between numbers is hardly evidence that the exceptions outnumber the common problems. :-) Do you know for certain that the number under the Community column is solely all regular user review? What if those flags were dismissed because the question was deleted (through auto-deletions when a moderator deletes an account, for example)? I think you are making too many assumptions.

Comment: It would be *possible*, @Joe. Post feature-requests on the meta sites you'd like to see.

Comment: @BhargavRao `Comment flags handled` also.

Comment: @BhargavRao I am probably one of those reviewers who passes many answer flags to moderators from LQ queue. I vote to recommend deletion on "canonical" non-answers and VLQ posts but I skip try-this and code-only garbage because these don't qualify for "Looks OK" to me

Comment: @MartijnPieters the only assumption I made was that the volume of NAA and VLQ has to be more than the aggregated of the other three flags combined, and apparently I was right. You guys are handling almost twice NAA flags than community [according with Shog graph.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340815/2016-a-year-in-moderation#comment428250_340865)

Comment: @Braiam: Don't base that on the totals. The way those flags are handled changed in early 2014, only since then has the community been stepping in in a major capacity. The totals in table at the bottom are *way* skewed because of that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters GRRR! Man that graph is impossible to read. I think I see the size of the light blue zone more or less of the same size of the darker one...

Comment: @Braiam: The graph is next to useless here, agreed. I *think* that lately, with the influx of the new mods, us mods have been handling NAAs a little more often than the community, but only because we now regularly have the flag queue tamed between us (so there is a little extra bandwidth to expand into the flags that we expect the community to handle and appear delayed on our radar).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, I'm not stating that "the community needs to handle more answer flags", I'm actually hinting at [decreasing the number of reviews needed for deleting the post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319133/4099593). As for close votes, the moderators do vote to close anything that needs immediate attention. (However, I'll try to spend some more time trying to clean the CVQ also, Thanks for that)

Comment: @JoshCaswell, Thanks, that actually makes a lot of sense. I was a bit blinded by the fact that I've been used to flag only NAAs. Now that the graph below has splits, It's time to look at those.

Comment: There is a grand irony that moderator eligibility is often strongly related to the question "why aren't you active in the review queue?" during elections, and yet once elected review queues are not even a priority. Perhaps more users will understand that moderators have to deal with problems more serious than just "is this link only post an answer" once elected by seeing this post.

Comment: Review queues are sort of a proxy for the mod queue, @Travis (at one time they were actually quite similar in terms of functionality). Ideally, we'd have folks in the community handling *all* of the flags initially, escalating to mods in cases where that wasn't feasible; in practice, that's tricky.

Comment: @MartijnPieters now the interactive graph is more useful. Apparently, most of the year, mods have been handling more NAA flags than community does, through the community seems to handle more VLQ/NAA flags combined than moderators does. I'm not sure what conclusion get from that.

Comment: does the deleted posts (and comments) count author self deletions, or only deletions by community members other than the author?

Comment: Everything (asterisk) @Servy. See the linked post for details on that.

Comment: What are _posts bumped_?

Comment: [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747076/problems-reading-inputstream-from-a-uri-and-sending-through-an-outputstream-andr), @jaco0646 (automated "bump" in last active date).

Comment: Why are mods raising so many flags? Is this their way of saying "i'm not sure about this, let's get another eye on it"? Or perhaps after handling it it gets escalated to a CM that way?

Comment: Spam-flagging spam is a good idea for *anyone*, @Scimonster. For mods, they take effect immediately. Similar applies to comments.

Answer (score 41):

The one number here that jumps out at me is the Community-issued automatic suspensions for recreated puppet or troll accounts. Almost as many automatic suspensions (1421) were issued as manual ones by moderators (2256). That tells me that [this implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277230/automatically-suspend-accounts-recreated-after-a-moderator-deleted-the-original/278803#278803) seems to be working better than I expected.

I can tell from my own experience that these automatic suspensions have helped cut down on spam, trolling, and question ban evasion by catching people reusing credentials. However, I've seen a number of people recreate these accounts, wait out their automatic suspension, and carry on with bad behavior after that.

I wonder if it's worth evaluating a longer suspension period for these accounts than the 14 days currently applied. Do you have statistics for how many of these 1421 automatically suspended accounts went on to post again, how many were deleted / destroyed / suspended again, and how many were never used after the auto-suspension?

I guess what I'm trying to see is how many of these were decent contributors after the auto-suspension, because I suspect not many were. If the latter is the case, perhaps it might be time to bump up the auto-suspension duration to further curb abuse.

Answer (score 23):

Been a few questions in the comments as to how flags shake out between elected mods and community mods... Since I happened to have this chart around, I'm posting it to hopefully answer these questions.

#### Flags handled per month on Stack Overflow, 2016

Interactive version (run snippet)

```js
     function renderStackedArea(results)
   {
  var allCats = {};
  var dateToCats = {};
  for (let r of results.rows)
  {
     allCats[r[results.category]] = 0;
     dateToCats[r[results.date]] = dateToCats[r[results.date]]||{};
     dateToCats[r[results.date]][r[results.category]] = r[results.count];
  }

  var maxCatCount =0;
  var catCountsByDate = $.map(dateToCats, function(cats,date) 
  { 
     var r = {date: new Date(Number(date))};
     r.date.setMinutes(r.date.getMinutes()+r.date.getTimezoneOffset())
     var subtotal = 0;
     for (var cat in allCats)
     {
        r[cat] = cats[cat]||0;
        allCats[cat] += r[cat];
        subtotal += r[cat];
     }
     maxCatCount = Math.max(maxCatCount, subtotal);
     return r;
  })
  .sort( (a,b) => b.date-a.date );

  var margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 50},
      width = $("#results").width() - 20 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = $("#results").width()*0.6 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var format = d3.format(",.0f");

  var x = d3.scaleTime()
     .domain(d3.extent(catCountsByDate, function(d) { return d.date; }))
     .range([0, width]);

  var y = results.logScale ? d3.scaleLog().domain([1,maxCatCount]).range([height, 1])
     : d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, maxCatCount]).range([height,0]);

  var keys = d3.keys(allCats).sort( (a,b) => allCats[b] - allCats[a]);

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
     .domain(keys)
     .range([...d3.schemeCategory20c, ...d3.schemeCategory20b]);
     
  var stack = d3.stack()
     .keys(keys)
     .order(d3.stackOrderReverse); // for aesthetic reasons, sort areas inverse of total
      
  var reasons = stack(catCountsByDate);

  var area = d3.area()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
      .y0(function(d) { return y(results.logScale ? d[0]||1 : d[0]); })
      .y1(function(d) { return y(results.logScale ? d[1]||1 : d[1]); });

  var svg = d3.select("#results").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g") 
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
                
  var reason = svg.selectAll(".reason")
  .data(reasons)
  .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "reason");

  reason.append("path")
     .attr("class", "area")
     .attr("d", area)
     .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); });

  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
     .append("text")
        .attr("y", "-1em")
        .attr("x", -margin.left + "px")
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .text(results.count);          

  var legend = d3.select("#results").append("ul").attr('class', 'legend');

  var countFormatter = d3.format(",.0f");
  var maxDigits = countFormatter(allCats[keys[0]]).length;
  legend.selectAll('li')
      .data(keys)
      .enter()
      .append("li")
      .style('border', function(c) { return color(c)+" solid 3px"; })
  .text(function(c) { return (new Array(maxDigits+1-countFormatter(allCats[c]).length)).join('\xA0') + countFormatter(allCats[c]) + ': ' + c; })
  ;

  
  // stolen from http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136

  var tooltip = d3.select("#results")
     .append("div")
     .attr("class", "remove")
     .style("position", "absolute")
     .style("z-index", "20")
     .style("visibility", "hidden")
     .style("top", "5px")
     .style("right", "20px");
  
  var tipDateFormatter = d3.timeFormat("%b %Y");
     
  svg.selectAll(".reason")
     .attr("opacity", 1)
     .on("mouseover", function(d, i) 
     { 
        svg.selectAll(".reason").transition()
        .duration(250)
        .attr("opacity", function(d, j) { return j != i ? 0.6 : 1; })
     })
   .on("mousemove", function(d, i) 
     {
        var mousex = d3.mouse(this)[0];
        var invertedx = x.invert(mousex);

        var selectedMonth = catCountsByDate.sort( (a,b) => Math.abs(a.date-invertedx) - Math.abs(b.date-invertedx) )[0];

        d3.select(this)
           .classed("hover", true)
           .attr("stroke-width", "0.5px"), 
        tooltip.html( "<p>" + d.key + "<br>" + tipDateFormatter(selectedMonth.date) + ": " + countFormatter(selectedMonth[d.key]) + " " + results.count + "</p>" ).style("visibility", "visible");
     
     })
  .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
     svg.selectAll(".reason")
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .attr("opacity", "1");
     
     d3.select(this)
        .classed("hover", false)
        .attr("stroke-width", "0px"), tooltip.html( "<p></p>" ).style("visibility", "hidden");
  });
   }
     function Rowset2Iterable(rowset)
   {
  var ret = {};
  ret[Symbol.iterator] = function() 
  {
    var row = 0;

     return { next: function()
        {
           if ( row >= rowset.rows.length ) return { done: true};
           var ret = {};
           for (let i=0; i<rowset.columns.length; ++i) ret[rowset.columns[i].name] = rowset.rows[row][i];
           ++row;
           return {done: false, value: ret};
        } };
  };
  return ret;
   }
     var rawdata = {"columns":[{"name":"mo","type":"Date"},{"name":"FlagType","type":"Text"},{"name":"Flags Handled","type":"Number"}],"rows":[[1451606400000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by community",47],[1451606400000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by mods",1088],[1451606400000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by community",10177],[1451606400000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by mods",14697],[1451606400000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by community",406],[1451606400000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by mods",4987],[1451606400000,"Comment Obsolete handled by community",202],[1451606400000,"Comment Obsolete handled by mods",7358],[1451606400000,"Comment Other handled by community",37],[1451606400000,"Comment Other handled by mods",953],[1451606400000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by community",389],[1451606400000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by mods",954],[1451606400000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by community",160],[1451606400000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by mods",3381],[1451606400000,"Comment Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",1],[1451606400000,"Mod Revision Redaction Approval handled by mods",7],[1451606400000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by community",24],[1451606400000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by mods",144],[1451606400000,"Post Low Quality handled by community",6598],[1451606400000,"Post Low Quality handled by mods",2811],[1451606400000,"Post Offensive handled by community",456],[1451606400000,"Post Offensive handled by mods",562],[1451606400000,"Post Other handled by mods",3608],[1451606400000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by community",9],[1451606400000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by mods",37],[1451606400000,"Post Spam handled by community",2319],[1451606400000,"Post Spam handled by mods",2102],[1451606400000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by community",172],[1451606400000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by mods",123],[1451606400000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",39],[1451606400000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by mods",39],[1451606400000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOthersAuto handled by mods",2],[1451606400000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by community",3],[1451606400000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by mods",171],[1451606400000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by mods",3],[1451606400000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto handled by mods",14],[1451606400000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto handled by mods",6],[1451606400000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by community",62],[1451606400000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by mods",588],[1454284800000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by community",38],[1454284800000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by mods",1064],[1454284800000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by community",7887],[1454284800000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by mods",15566],[1454284800000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by community",455],[1454284800000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by mods",5752],[1454284800000,"Comment Obsolete handled by community",233],[1454284800000,"Comment Obsolete handled by mods",6318],[1454284800000,"Comment Other handled by community",67],[1454284800000,"Comment Other handled by mods",670],[1454284800000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by community",298],[1454284800000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by mods",1091],[1454284800000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by community",133],[1454284800000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by mods",3271],[1454284800000,"Comment Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",1],[1454284800000,"Mod Revision Redaction Approval handled by mods",25],[1454284800000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by community",30],[1454284800000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by mods",165],[1454284800000,"Post Low Quality handled by community",5979],[1454284800000,"Post Low Quality handled by mods",2890],[1454284800000,"Post Offensive handled by community",299],[1454284800000,"Post Offensive handled by mods",418],[1454284800000,"Post Other handled by mods",3231],[1454284800000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by community",8],[1454284800000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by mods",41],[1454284800000,"Post Spam handled by community",2221],[1454284800000,"Post Spam handled by mods",1869],[1454284800000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by community",226],[1454284800000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by mods",25],[1454284800000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",22],[1454284800000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by community",1],[1454284800000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by mods",14],[1454284800000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by community",1],[1454284800000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by mods",6],[1454284800000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by mods",2],[1454284800000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto handled by mods",13],[1454284800000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto handled by mods",6],[1454284800000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by community",47],[1454284800000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by mods",425],[1456790400000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by community",51],[1456790400000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by mods",1089],[1456790400000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by community",9868],[1456790400000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by mods",17304],[1456790400000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by community",315],[1456790400000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by mods",4251],[1456790400000,"Comment Obsolete handled by community",190],[1456790400000,"Comment Obsolete handled by mods",6976],[1456790400000,"Comment Other handled by community",46],[1456790400000,"Comment Other handled by mods",746],[1456790400000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by community",258],[1456790400000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by mods",1069],[1456790400000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by community",126],[1456790400000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by mods",4200],[1456790400000,"Comment Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",1],[1456790400000,"Mod Revision Redaction Approval handled by mods",50],[1456790400000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by community",31],[1456790400000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by mods",235],[1456790400000,"Post Low Quality handled by community",6920],[1456790400000,"Post Low Quality handled by mods",3142],[1456790400000,"Post Offensive handled by community",633],[1456790400000,"Post Offensive handled by mods",565],[1456790400000,"Post Other handled by community",23],[1456790400000,"Post Other handled by mods",3199],[1456790400000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by community",2],[1456790400000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by mods",38],[1456790400000,"Post Spam handled by community",2308],[1456790400000,"Post Spam handled by mods",1871],[1456790400000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by community",242],[1456790400000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by mods",40],[1456790400000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",32],[1456790400000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by mods",23],[1456790400000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by mods",8],[1456790400000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by community",1],[1456790400000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by mods",8],[1456790400000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto handled by mods",17],[1456790400000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto handled by mods",13],[1456790400000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by community",100],[1456790400000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by mods",590],[1459468800000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by community",50],[1459468800000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by mods",1095],[1459468800000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by community",8127],[1459468800000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by mods",14220],[1459468800000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by community",373],[1459468800000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by mods",4195],[1459468800000,"Comment Obsolete handled by community",210],[1459468800000,"Comment Obsolete handled by mods",6389],[1459468800000,"Comment Other handled by community",47],[1459468800000,"Comment Other handled by mods",709],[1459468800000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by community",286],[1459468800000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by mods",941],[1459468800000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by community",132],[1459468800000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by mods",3218],[1459468800000,"Comment Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",1],[1459468800000,"Mod Revision Redaction Approval handled by mods",52],[1459468800000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by community",33],[1459468800000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by mods",139],[1459468800000,"Post Low Quality handled by community",6579],[1459468800000,"Post Low Quality handled by mods",2603],[1459468800000,"Post Offensive handled by community",908],[1459468800000,"Post Offensive handled by mods",561],[1459468800000,"Post Other handled by mods",3470],[1459468800000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by community",3],[1459468800000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by mods",30],[1459468800000,"Post Spam handled by community",1895],[1459468800000,"Post Spam handled by mods",1854],[1459468800000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by community",252],[1459468800000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by mods",21],[1459468800000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",18],[1459468800000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by mods",6],[1459468800000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by mods",14],[1459468800000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by mods",4],[1459468800000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto handled by mods",3],[1459468800000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto handled by mods",10],[1459468800000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by community",61],[1459468800000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by mods",382],[1459468800000,"Team Offensive handled by mods",2],[1462060800000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by community",55],[1462060800000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by mods",1127],[1462060800000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by community",9729],[1462060800000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by mods",13864],[1462060800000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by community",348],[1462060800000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by mods",5725],[1462060800000,"Comment Obsolete handled by community",2660],[1462060800000,"Comment Obsolete handled by mods",6297],[1462060800000,"Comment Other handled by community",47],[1462060800000,"Comment Other handled by mods",738],[1462060800000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by community",330],[1462060800000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by mods",933],[1462060800000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by community",125],[1462060800000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by mods",3397],[1462060800000,"Mod Revision Redaction Approval handled by mods",35],[1462060800000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by community",41],[1462060800000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by mods",165],[1462060800000,"Post Low Quality handled by community",7004],[1462060800000,"Post Low Quality handled by mods",2842],[1462060800000,"Post Offensive handled by community",799],[1462060800000,"Post Offensive handled by mods",698],[1462060800000,"Post Other handled by mods",3340],[1462060800000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by mods",27],[1462060800000,"Post Spam handled by community",1661],[1462060800000,"Post Spam handled by mods",1642],[1462060800000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by community",234],[1462060800000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by mods",12],[1462060800000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",39],[1462060800000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by community",1],[1462060800000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by mods",18],[1462060800000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by mods",13],[1462060800000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by community",1],[1462060800000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by mods",2],[1462060800000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto handled by mods",12],[1462060800000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto handled by mods",6],[1462060800000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by community",56],[1462060800000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by mods",595],[1464739200000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by community",38],[1464739200000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by mods",1115],[1464739200000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by community",7892],[1464739200000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by mods",14450],[1464739200000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by community",311],[1464739200000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by mods",4473],[1464739200000,"Comment Obsolete handled by community",3022],[1464739200000,"Comment Obsolete handled by mods",6573],[1464739200000,"Comment Other handled by community",48],[1464739200000,"Comment Other handled by mods",637],[1464739200000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by community",417],[1464739200000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by mods",1022],[1464739200000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by community",78],[1464739200000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by mods",4367],[1464739200000,"Mod Revision Redaction Approval handled by mods",38],[1464739200000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by community",16],[1464739200000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by mods",138],[1464739200000,"Post Low Quality handled by community",5873],[1464739200000,"Post Low Quality handled by mods",3192],[1464739200000,"Post Offensive handled by community",725],[1464739200000,"Post Offensive handled by mods",555],[1464739200000,"Post Other handled by mods",3047],[1464739200000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by community",1],[1464739200000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by mods",31],[1464739200000,"Post Spam handled by community",1941],[1464739200000,"Post Spam handled by mods",1755],[1464739200000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by community",166],[1464739200000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by mods",76],[1464739200000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",98],[1464739200000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by community",1],[1464739200000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by mods",74],[1464739200000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by mods",12],[1464739200000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by mods",5],[1464739200000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto handled by mods",49],[1464739200000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto handled by mods",7],[1464739200000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by community",49],[1464739200000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by mods",446],[1467331200000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by community",55],[1467331200000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by mods",1115],[1467331200000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by community",8024],[1467331200000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by mods",14934],[1467331200000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by community",420],[1467331200000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by mods",5217],[1467331200000,"Comment Obsolete handled by community",2351],[1467331200000,"Comment Obsolete handled by mods",6136],[1467331200000,"Comment Other handled by community",58],[1467331200000,"Comment Other handled by mods",637],[1467331200000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by community",427],[1467331200000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by mods",995],[1467331200000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by community",128],[1467331200000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by mods",3717],[1467331200000,"Comment Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",1],[1467331200000,"Mod Revision Redaction Approval handled by mods",45],[1467331200000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by community",18],[1467331200000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by mods",41],[1467331200000,"Post Low Quality handled by community",5472],[1467331200000,"Post Low Quality handled by mods",2191],[1467331200000,"Post Offensive handled by community",402],[1467331200000,"Post Offensive handled by mods",554],[1467331200000,"Post Other handled by mods",2984],[1467331200000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by community",2],[1467331200000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by mods",19],[1467331200000,"Post Spam handled by community",1386],[1467331200000,"Post Spam handled by mods",1862],[1467331200000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by community",260],[1467331200000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by mods",27],[1467331200000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",19],[1467331200000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by community",1],[1467331200000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by mods",7],[1467331200000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by mods",2],[1467331200000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by community",1],[1467331200000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by mods",4],[1467331200000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto handled by mods",4],[1467331200000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto handled by mods",3],[1467331200000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by community",46],[1467331200000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by mods",389],[1470009600000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by community",61],[1470009600000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by mods",1163],[1470009600000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by community",8615],[1470009600000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by mods",14224],[1470009600000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by community",657],[1470009600000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by mods",5039],[1470009600000,"Comment Obsolete handled by community",2795],[1470009600000,"Comment Obsolete handled by mods",6356],[1470009600000,"Comment Other handled by community",69],[1470009600000,"Comment Other handled by mods",723],[1470009600000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by community",669],[1470009600000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by mods",1204],[1470009600000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by community",218],[1470009600000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by mods",4025],[1470009600000,"Comment Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",1],[1470009600000,"Mod Revision Redaction Approval handled by mods",36],[1470009600000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by community",11],[1470009600000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by mods",64],[1470009600000,"Post Low Quality handled by community",5717],[1470009600000,"Post Low Quality handled by mods",2323],[1470009600000,"Post Offensive handled by community",516],[1470009600000,"Post Offensive handled by mods",557],[1470009600000,"Post Other handled by community",59],[1470009600000,"Post Other handled by mods",3302],[1470009600000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by community",1],[1470009600000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by mods",21],[1470009600000,"Post Spam handled by community",2181],[1470009600000,"Post Spam handled by mods",1985],[1470009600000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by community",240],[1470009600000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by mods",33],[1470009600000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",44],[1470009600000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by mods",25],[1470009600000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by mods",17],[1470009600000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by community",1],[1470009600000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by mods",4],[1470009600000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto handled by mods",19],[1470009600000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto handled by mods",11],[1470009600000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by community",50],[1470009600000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by mods",415],[1470009600000,"Team Other handled by mods",1],[1472688000000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by community",45],[1472688000000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by mods",1112],[1472688000000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by community",7073],[1472688000000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by mods",16517],[1472688000000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by community",482],[1472688000000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by mods",4423],[1472688000000,"Comment Obsolete handled by community",2996],[1472688000000,"Comment Obsolete handled by mods",6064],[1472688000000,"Comment Other handled by community",45],[1472688000000,"Comment Other handled by mods",595],[1472688000000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by community",404],[1472688000000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by mods",1000],[1472688000000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by community",179],[1472688000000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by mods",3997],[1472688000000,"CommentTooManyDeletedRudeNotConstructiveAuto handled by community",5],[1472688000000,"CommentTooManyDeletedRudeNotConstructiveAuto handled by mods",11],[1472688000000,"Mod Revision Redaction Approval handled by mods",27],[1472688000000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by community",14],[1472688000000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by mods",53],[1472688000000,"Post Low Quality handled by community",5291],[1472688000000,"Post Low Quality handled by mods",2385],[1472688000000,"Post Offensive handled by community",481],[1472688000000,"Post Offensive handled by mods",498],[1472688000000,"Post Other handled by community",73],[1472688000000,"Post Other handled by mods",2864],[1472688000000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by community",1],[1472688000000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by mods",19],[1472688000000,"Post Spam handled by community",2267],[1472688000000,"Post Spam handled by mods",1956],[1472688000000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by community",218],[1472688000000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by mods",25],[1472688000000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",21],[1472688000000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by mods",17],[1472688000000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by mods",2],[1472688000000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by mods",4],[1472688000000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto handled by mods",21],[1472688000000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto handled by mods",6],[1472688000000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by community",44],[1472688000000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by mods",249],[1475280000000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by community",40],[1475280000000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by mods",1158],[1475280000000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by community",6033],[1475280000000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by mods",17591],[1475280000000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by community",406],[1475280000000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by mods",4023],[1475280000000,"Comment Obsolete handled by community",3040],[1475280000000,"Comment Obsolete handled by mods",6335],[1475280000000,"Comment Other handled by community",56],[1475280000000,"Comment Other handled by mods",608],[1475280000000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by community",381],[1475280000000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by mods",1008],[1475280000000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by community",116],[1475280000000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by mods",4062],[1475280000000,"Comment Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",2],[1475280000000,"CommentTooManyDeletedRudeNotConstructiveAuto handled by community",47],[1475280000000,"CommentTooManyDeletedRudeNotConstructiveAuto handled by mods",404],[1475280000000,"Mod Revision Redaction Approval handled by mods",30],[1475280000000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by community",5],[1475280000000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by mods",89],[1475280000000,"Post Low Quality handled by community",5769],[1475280000000,"Post Low Quality handled by mods",2701],[1475280000000,"Post Offensive handled by community",671],[1475280000000,"Post Offensive handled by mods",566],[1475280000000,"Post Other handled by community",43],[1475280000000,"Post Other handled by mods",3012],[1475280000000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by community",5],[1475280000000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by mods",25],[1475280000000,"Post Spam handled by community",1935],[1475280000000,"Post Spam handled by mods",1832],[1475280000000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by community",237],[1475280000000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by mods",31],[1475280000000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",79],[1475280000000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by mods",36],[1475280000000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by mods",28],[1475280000000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by community",2],[1475280000000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by mods",18],[1475280000000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto handled by mods",44],[1475280000000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto handled by mods",16],[1475280000000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by community",29],[1475280000000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by mods",400],[1477958400000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by community",57],[1477958400000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by mods",1088],[1477958400000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by community",5866],[1477958400000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by mods",20486],[1477958400000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by community",383],[1477958400000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by mods",4348],[1477958400000,"Comment Obsolete handled by community",2989],[1477958400000,"Comment Obsolete handled by mods",6712],[1477958400000,"Comment Other handled by community",57],[1477958400000,"Comment Other handled by mods",696],[1477958400000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by community",328],[1477958400000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by mods",917],[1477958400000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by community",167],[1477958400000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by mods",7027],[1477958400000,"CommentTooManyDeletedRudeNotConstructiveAuto handled by community",19],[1477958400000,"CommentTooManyDeletedRudeNotConstructiveAuto handled by mods",382],[1477958400000,"Mod Revision Redaction Approval handled by mods",47],[1477958400000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by community",2],[1477958400000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by mods",28],[1477958400000,"Post Low Quality handled by community",6093],[1477958400000,"Post Low Quality handled by mods",3285],[1477958400000,"Post Offensive handled by community",544],[1477958400000,"Post Offensive handled by mods",657],[1477958400000,"Post Other handled by community",93],[1477958400000,"Post Other handled by mods",2997],[1477958400000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by community",1],[1477958400000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by mods",24],[1477958400000,"Post Spam handled by community",1446],[1477958400000,"Post Spam handled by mods",1831],[1477958400000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by community",189],[1477958400000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by mods",54],[1477958400000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by community",13],[1477958400000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",85],[1477958400000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by mods",8],[1477958400000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by mods",16],[1477958400000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by community",1],[1477958400000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by mods",7],[1477958400000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto handled by mods",9],[1477958400000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto handled by mods",11],[1477958400000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by community",32],[1477958400000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by mods",418],[1480550400000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by community",33],[1480550400000,"Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto) handled by mods",1019],[1480550400000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by community",2948],[1480550400000,"Answer Not An Answer handled by mods",18286],[1480550400000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by community",1201],[1480550400000,"Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic handled by mods",4690],[1480550400000,"Comment Obsolete handled by community",3685],[1480550400000,"Comment Obsolete handled by mods",6410],[1480550400000,"Comment Other handled by community",58],[1480550400000,"Comment Other handled by mods",657],[1480550400000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by community",319],[1480550400000,"Comment Rude Or Offensive handled by mods",944],[1480550400000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by community",301],[1480550400000,"Comment Too Chatty handled by mods",4403],[1480550400000,"Comment Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",1],[1480550400000,"CommentTooManyDeletedRudeNotConstructiveAuto handled by community",16],[1480550400000,"CommentTooManyDeletedRudeNotConstructiveAuto handled by mods",262],[1480550400000,"Mod Revision Redaction Approval handled by mods",56],[1480550400000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by community",3],[1480550400000,"Post Excessively Long (Auto) handled by mods",19],[1480550400000,"Post Low Quality handled by community",3529],[1480550400000,"Post Low Quality handled by mods",3162],[1480550400000,"Post Offensive handled by community",291],[1480550400000,"Post Offensive handled by mods",517],[1480550400000,"Post Other handled by community",51],[1480550400000,"Post Other handled by mods",2773],[1480550400000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by community",6],[1480550400000,"Post Rollback War (Auto) handled by mods",17],[1480550400000,"Post Spam handled by community",1336],[1480550400000,"Post Spam handled by mods",1735],[1480550400000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by community",53],[1480550400000,"Post Too Many Comments (Auto) handled by mods",239],[1480550400000,"Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto) handled by mods",44],[1480550400000,"Post Vandalism Edits (Auto) handled by mods",2],[1480550400000,"PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto handled by mods",17],[1480550400000,"QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto handled by mods",2],[1480550400000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto handled by mods",15],[1480550400000,"QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto handled by mods",6],[1480550400000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by community",13],[1480550400000,"ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto handled by mods",116]],"messagePosition":0,"truncated":false};
     var chartData = { 
        logScale: false,
        date: rawdata.columns[0].name, 
        category: rawdata.columns[1].name, 
        count: rawdata.columns[2].name, 
        rows: Rowset2Iterable(rawdata)
     };
     
     renderStackedArea(chartData);
     
     var debounce;
     $(window).resize(function()
     {
        clearTimeout(debounce);
        debounce = setTimeout(function(){ $("#results").empty(); renderStackedArea(chartData) },2000);
     });
```

```css
     
     #results 
     {
       font: 10px sans-serif;
        position: relative;
       text-shadow: white 0 0 6px;
     }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .reason text {
    text-anchor: end;
  }

  .legend
  {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .legend li
  {
   list-style-type:none;
    padding: .25em;
    text-shadow: white 0 0 6px;
    font-size:10pt;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .y.axis text
  {
     fill: black;
     text-shadow: white 0 0 6px;
  }
```

```html
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src='//d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.45.min.js'></script>
     <div id='results'></div>
```

Static version:

[image: flags handled per month graph, 2016]
[image: flags handled per month data, 2016]

Comment: Can someone explain this graph to me? What's the difference between Answer NAA and Community-handled Answer NAA? Are them subset one of the other?

Comment: Answer NAA is moderator-handled, Community-handled Answer NAA is not, @Braiam.

Comment: @Shog9 The edit summary for this answer's second revision says "added 32950 characters in body", but nothing seems to have changed.  What happened?

Comment: Hit the wrong button, @Jeffrey. Snippets editor likes to freak out when you're dumping a lot of data into it. See new edit.

Comment: You happened to have this chart around from your old geocities webpage? :P Can we get a little less contrast on the legend?

Comment: I posted the code and all the data in the snippet, @TravisJ - feel free to edit, or just send me a list of ~50 colors.

Comment: @Shog9 - Hopefully that retains the legend's intent while lowering the contrast of the data. If not, feel free to roll back the change.

Comment: @TravisJ I think it was perfectly readable beforehand, but then again my monitor's contrast/brightness might be configured differently.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I had to squint to read the text in first interactions.