# Is it OK to re-upload externally hosted images on Stack Overflow's imgur?

Tags: discussion, edits, images

In my country imgur is blocked and can only accessible through VPNs. I can use VPN on my mobile or PC but can't use it while I'm at work, so if an image is uploaded directly to imgur, I can't see that but I can see images that uploaded via stackoverflow's upload feature (to i.stack.imgur).

To show what it is like, this is what I see on [direct imgur used answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340865/3134251) (I used this because this is the latest I encountered).

[image]

I can workaround it using image upload.

[image]

After clicking Add Picture, now it's uploaded to i.stack.imgur and I can see the image.

So, my question is, if I feel like to change it, is it OK to edit direct imgur links to i.stack.imgur ones without notifying OP or should I just see the image myself and move on?

<sub>p.s. Couldn't find a better title, so feel free to change it. Also wasn't sure to post on meta.se or here.</sub>

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> Is it OK to edit direct imgur links to i.stack.imgur ones without notifying OP or should I just see the image myself and move on?

Yes, this is fine. There should only be a few old posts that you will come across that *don't* use the official Stack Overflow image-hosting service, hailing from a time before that service was available and well-integrated. Currently, someone would have to work extra hard *not* to upload to `i.stack.imgur.com`.

You don't need to notify anyone. In fact, it's better if you *don't* notify anyone—you have full edit privileges, so just make the edit. Why waste two people's time?

The only thing I would ask is that, while you're making these image-substitution edits, you also fix any other glaring problems with the post that you see. If the post has incorrectly formatted code, fix it. If a question is obviously mistagged, fix it. If the title uses horribly inappropriate grammar, change it. And so on. You don't have to fix *everything* if you're short on time, but taking care of the obvious issues will help to minimize the disruptive impact of edits.

Comment: Searching by [i.stack.imgur.com](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=i.stack.imgur.com) yields 13,295 results while searching by [i.imgur.com](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=i.imgur.com) yields 13,755 results. That's odd to me.

Comment: @Zanon: That doesn't include image (or link) URLs, just posts where the hostname is mentioned in visible text. Prepending `url:` to the search will find link URLs (including any recent image uploaded since the upload wizard was changed to also include a link to the image), but I'm pretty sure that you'd need an SEDE query (something like the opposite of [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/430352/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur)) to actually count image URLs properly.

Comment: What of licensing? I used to do these en masse (especially for image services shutting down), but I noticed that most external services don't seem to have compatible licensing schemes. Thoughts?

Comment: @Undo That's actually what I thought this question was going to be about when I clicked on it.

Comment: @Undo Technically, unless the third-party license is compatible with CC BY-SA 3.0, reuploading an image to i.stack.imgur counts as redistribution, which in the case of incompatible licenses is likely to be illegal.

Comment: @undo I don't think where the image is hosted changes the licensing. There are sites that have restrictions on hot linking to images (and instead require you to link to the site itself so you can see the image in context), so yes, moving those to another service and embedding them would probably be illegal. But I don't think that is true for moving an image from i.imgur.com to i.stack.imgur.com. The license remains intact, and belongs to the person who originally contributed the image. They're still getting the credit.

Comment: @CodyGray If the OP had authorised the upload to image service A, but hasn't authorised the upload to image service B, then you may be right that uploading it to image service B doesn't change the license, but that's exactly what potentially *makes* it illegal.

Comment: @hvd If you've put the image *inline* in your Stack Overflow answer, it becomes licensed by Stack Overflow's standard CC BY-SA license. That changes the license. The OP can't restrict the upload rights exclusively to image service A. Stack Overflow is allowed to mirror it under the conditions of its license, and i.stack.imgur.com is Stack Overflow's official image-hosting website.

Comment: @CodyGray Embedding it into SO doesn't change the fact that it was never uploaded by the OP to any SO-backed service. Additionally, commonly, new posts link to the images, they don't show the images inline. That's done by others with editing privileges.

Comment: @CodyGray Another point, the [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) is claimed to be "an anonymized dump of **all user-contributed content** on the Stack Exchange network" (emphasis mine). It doesn't include images. My conclusion would be that the images aren't counted as user-contributed content, and from that, I would conclude that "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required" doesn't apply to them.

Comment: @hvd If the image is displayed inline, then you've effectively "hosted" it on SO, irrespective of where it was originally uploaded. That's my whole point, and that's why moving its hosting to SO-affiliated service is legitimate. If you don't want to license your images CC BY-SA, then you can't display them inline. Now, your second point about people editing the images inline is a stickier problem. This is potentially a license violation, and maybe they shouldn't be doing that without permission. I don't think that's a valid conclusion to draw from the dump; it's probably technical limitations.

Comment: @CodyGray There was a big deal a few years back in the Germany, about someone who had embedded an illegally uploaded Youtube video on a personal web site. It went to the EU court, which ruled that no, embedding it is legally very different from hosting it. I have no idea if the situation is the same in the US, but I wouldn't be too quick in assuming that embedding counts as hosting. (Link: https://yro.slashdot.org/story/14/10/27/0051224/eu-court-rules-embedding-youtube-videos-is-not-copyright-infringement)

Comment: I could argue about whether that's the same, given the way that YouTube embeds are set up with frames, etc. But really, it's a fair point, and someone should ask a lawyer if they want the real answer. I can only provide my unofficial opinion.

Comment: *`Yes, this is fine.`* – Erm, just to clarify: does this fall under “fair use”? After all, images tend to be copyrighted.

Comment: No, it doesn't fall under "fair use". My claim is it that it doesn't change or affect the copyright whatsoever. @e-sushi.