# Should I edit questions with unformatted Imgur links?

Tags: discussion, imgur

Once in a while, I come across a post that has an [Imgur](https://imgur.com/) link, but with no visible picture. When I see this, I edit the post and format the link in a way that the image becomes viewable on the post. The only time I don't do this is when there are numerous [Imgur](https://imgur.com/) links and this is to avoid bloating up the post.

Is this a good practice? Are some unformatted Imgur links meant to be left as is?

Comment: Yes. Always edit questions so that the images are visible except for code images.

Comment: Certainly a post with a bunch of malformed images, eg. a bunch of `[enter image description here][1]` links that don't actually show an image, is pretty annoying. There's probably an argument that posts with multiple of these are usually of poorer quality to begin with, though.

Comment: Only if the image is then viewable. Some images are so huge that displaying them inline makes it impossible to see any detail - in which case they are best left as a link and a comment posted to encourage the poster not to use images, or only show a minimal image to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Related: [How to review edits that add images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350212) and [Is it OK to re-upload externally hosted images on Stack Overflow's imgur?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341016).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Yes.**

Always edit a question if it has images as links, *except* for when they're images of text.

It is annoying for answerers to have to swap between tabs when you answer to see the image.  For code images, that's a different rule.

Also sometimes the text on the image link is just "enter image description here", which confuses answerers. It's best to directly show the image.

Comment: This should also be avoided when it's a screenshot of the error message and most other screenshots of text. If you can also replace the placeholder "enter image description here" with [good alt text with terminating punctuation](https://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/), that would be awesome.

Comment: Side note: Many graphical IDEs will have a tab, dialog, or some UI element that displays the raw build output as text. This will paste into questions very easily. In addition the full build output often contains more information than its graphical overview version and this extra information is often exactly what you needed to understand the problem.

Comment: Maybe also mention the possibility to change the display size of the images with some suffixes (m,s, ..). There must be a link to it somewhere. If only we could specify the displayed size of images even more (like in %, that would be great).

Comment: "Always" is pretty strong. Just today I came across an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57915162/6243352) where I thought I could improve it by inlining the image. Upon doing so, I found a massive amount of blank space at the bottom of the image that would have negatively impacted readability of the thread as a whole. Not being interested in going down the path of cropping it on behalf of OP, I left the image as a link and canceled my edit.

Answer (score 20):

To expand on [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402683):

This typically comes up when a new user without sufficient privilege to inline the image includes one anyway. By editing the post, you are vetting the image as a privileged user, verifying that it includes relevant and non-objectionable content, and improving the experience for most users.

It's true that excessive images can be annoying to some (especially those of us with limited Internet connections), but as long as they add something to the question, it is better to go ahead and have them visible when the page loads.

Editing is usually pretty easy. In most cases, all you have to do is add the `!` character before the bracketed link to indicate that it's an image to display.

While you are editing, you should also replace any placeholder *"enter image description here"* text with something more useful. The users who rely on this descriptive text for accessibility will very much appreciate it, and it also enhances searchability (images aren't generally searchable, but useful text describing the image can help them show up in Google anyway).

Finally, the one except to all of the above is when the post itself isn't very high quality to start with and including the image isn't going to help. We occasionally have users who post their code as a screenshot, which is pointless. I don't see any utility in fixing those posts to show the code; the author of the question needs to remove the image altogether and replace it with the *text* of their code, so inlining the image doesn't add anything useful there and I wouldn't bother.

But otherwise, by all means…improve those posts.

Comment: The limit is 10 reputation points, *"Remove new-user restrictions"* (the information [is on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di/160292#160292) (see the footnotes - *"post images"*), but not on [the too-terse help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)).

Comment: If the image is large, you should also make the image a link, so `[img][1]` turns into markdown like this: `[ ![foo][1] ][1]`.  People can of course right click "open image in new tab", but if you expect that's something most readers will want to do (or will have to to make some too-big image readable if it contains text), then make it a link.  Usually only happens with bad images that should have been code-formatting blocks in the first place, though.  But if you *do* choose to edit questions like that, it can save other people time deciding whether to definitely DV or wait for improvement.

Comment: I typically would just take 30 seconds and shrink the image by 80% using the built-in photo editor when doing an edit like this.  If the size annoys me I know it will annoy others

Comment: "occasionally have users who post their code as a screenshot" your definition of "occasionally" must be different to mine.

Comment: @Security Cropping can also help sometimes, but err on the side of caution, i.e. crop less, just in case there's relevant info in the surroundings

Comment: **That’s the reason I shrink the image not crop it.**
 Which is the rereason I said shrink not crop

Comment: @IanKemp: _"your definition of "occasionally" must be different to mine"_ -- maybe. Or maybe we just see different posts. I look at very few SO questions these days...just too much crap, and too little time on my hands.

Answer (score 6):

**It depends.**

If the question contains *only* images, and/or is from a new user who lacks the reputation to post images, you need to take a **very** careful look at those images. If they're screenshots of code, or stack traces, or anything that is actually material to the question or answer, then immediately stop editing that question, and instead vote to close it. That question is unsalvageable until or unless the asker edits the actual code and error message text into it, and they're the only one who can do that; editing such a question, which is sure to be closed, is a waste of your edit time, and a waste of time of the people in the review queue.

In all other cases, sure. In particular, when a new user without the rep to add images has asked a good question with linked images, feel free to help them out by directly embedding their images. It's still your responsibility to ensure that those images are appropriate.