# Some data from SEDE that I found cool

Tags: discussion

Now that 2016 have finished I spent some time (and a few questions) with SEDE. I decided to make a data chart with graphs about the questions and answers volume and on average how many net positive votes were received on average. Without further ado, my spreadsheet!

[image: The data]

So the text may be small so [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S0ft.jpg) is an Imgur link to the photo.

## My takeaway

OK. So after many things were pointed out to me, I would like to see more upvotes on quality posts. Many quality posts are undervoted. I am glad the amount of answers didn't drop much in the inactive months. Keep up the good work! So what is your takeaway from 2016?

## DISCLAIMER

This is *my* opinion, so you may not agree. My main point was to give the data I spent ~45 min in total getting the data and compiling into a spreadsheet.

Comment: hmm... should we upvote more, or, should people asking questions/posting answers ask better questions/post better answers...

Comment: the December inactivity gets addressed already, it's called Winterbash

Comment: @yellowantphil I was mainly referring to answers.

Comment: Why is a ratio of 3:1 for upvotes:downvotes ideal? Or maybe you think it should be 1:1? It's a bit unclear why we need more upvotes...

Comment: Encouraging upvoting for no reason other than to improve the upvote:downvote ratio is a terrible idea. Perhaps the reason the ratio is 'bad' is because there are more bad questions than good ones?

Comment: I am.... not sure what we are trying to do here and fix or discuss or whatnot.... it's just graphs and data... why are slow months a problem?

Comment: could you post the queries you use to get this data?

Comment: Also (just realized I busted the edit limit).....why do we arbitrarily need more upvotes? Content is rated by its quality.... we don't need a quota for voting... we need better stuff to vote on

Comment: @Patrice Fixed my post

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Fixed my post

Comment: @ChristopherPeart you want a discussion, but you can't tolerate having ANY disagreement? I am trying to understand where you are coming from SO we can discuss....

Comment: I can understand that @yellowantphil

Comment: @Patrice let me re write this

Comment: @ChristopherPeart even after the rewrite... not sure what you mean. Do you have examples of good posts without votes? I do not see the logic behind "we should upvote more", without seeing any proof that we do not have enough upvotes... Right now it seems like you are just saying that without anything to back it up except your gut feeling :/...

Comment: Also considering how quickly I could go to the main page and find terrible questions with upvotes or without downvotes.... the point we don't upvote enough is hard to believe is right...

Comment: I did say upvote more on quality posts

Comment: I never said that all questions were good or even many.

Comment: @Patrice I found answers that I believe should be better voted then they are.

Comment: What's with the squiggle above the first graph?

Comment: idk actually it wouldn't go away in excel

Comment: @ChristopherPeart That YOU believe.... that goes back to me saying "besides you saying it's your gut feeling.... proof?" Any link to these good, un-upvoted posts? Right now, all I can think of is the constant deluge of terrible questions and I would say that we should downvote MORE.... but yeah.  Anyway "not as upvoted as they should be" isn't really a system that should work for Stack... There is no such thing as "a question worth +5".... So unless they are NOT voted on at all.... then saying "not as upvoted as should be" just isn't how the site works...

Comment: Just like we tell people they shouldn't vote to correct other votes (ie: "Oh this isn't SO bad a question... not worth -5, lemme bring it to -4")...

Comment: again, it would be good to see the queries you used to collect this data. you suggest that we should vote on more quality posts yet you make no such distinction between questions and answers in your data. also i am curious if your getting votes based on the time the vote was made rather than tallying votes on questions in the past year (which then ignore all existing high quality content)

Comment: Of note, the trend in the "Downvotes" graph is seemingly identical to the trend in the "Upvotes" graph. This seems to be in direct relation to the number of posts being asked in a given day / week / month. The system is working, medium to high quality posts are getting upvoted over time, low quality posts are getting downvoted. Does your dataset include deleted posts?

Comment: You should probably include the queries, and a copy of the spreadsheet at the very least. What would be great is if you did something like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340865/4639281) with an interactive graph.

Comment: @TinyGiant i don't think SEDE include deleted posts, at least that's what i remember reading on Meta

Comment: @Memor-X there is PostsWithDeleted but I'm not sure if that includes up / down votes or not, and am too lazy too look

Comment: @tiny The squiggle looks like a sparkline graph in Excel, which is basically a tiny graph within a single cell. Very cool feature.

Comment: @Cody Ah yes, I remember reading about that at one point.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> The months of July and December are the most inactive. We should try and improve that.

Why would we need to do anything about it?  You'll note that this is largely driven by when students are in/not in school, and when professionals are taking time off, so there isn't really much to be done about this anyway.

> I personally believe that we as a community should upvote more.

You're putting the cart before the horse.  We want to *have more content worthy of being upvoted* on the site.  Upvoting bad content doesn't mean that the site has better content, it just means that the site is less effectively indicating the quality of the content that it has.  If there are more upvotes *because there is simply more good content* then that's quite different.

So if you want to see more upvotes then consider *how you can encourage people to post better content* rather than how you can convince people to upvote a post that they don't think merits an upvote.

Comment: I changed up my post to fix all the problems pointed out.

Comment: In addition to the conceptual arguments you make here, I'd point to the fact that the "upvotes" and "downvotes" graphs seem to track pretty consistently, suggesting that it is not merely people failing to upvote, but rather a reflection of the fact that participation is just down.