# Can we get closure statistics for all of 2016?

Tags: support, statistics

I recently discovered [the Closure statistics 10k tool](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last30days). It's pretty great, if you have a reputation of at least 10K. But... It only covers at most the last 30 days.

And the last 30 days ain't no good. I want to do things with this information, *devious* things, *things* that depend on being able to cross-reference with [2016: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340815/2016-a-year-in-moderation) and [2016: a year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289797/2016-a-year-in-closing)... And I can't do that for "the last 30 days".

So, can we have closure stats for all of 2016? kthxbye.

Comment: I would assume somewhere in the range of 3% or lower.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last30days

Comment: @Shog9, well then, I guess I didn't look hard enough. I've never looked at that page before. Does "Reopened" on that page include or exclude "Edited and Reopened"?

Comment: Includes. So, subtract.

Comment: @Shog9 No chance of getting the same stats for a longer time period? The max there is 30 days, I was hoping for a year.

Comment: "kthxbye"? Really? That's what we're doing now? What idiot would add su....ah ... fine. This is fine.

Comment: I see in the list that Shog9 linked that Will at one point created the close reason to end all close reasons: *"Well, this kind of sucks. Wish I could remove it."* I guess no chance of us ever getting that reinstated permanently? :-(

Comment: Interesting to see the custom close reasons. There's around 50 different versions of "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming." Seems we need such a close reason. On other SE sites there is often a close reason "blatantly off-topic".

Comment: @Lundin "Blatantly off-topic" is also there instead of the custom reason for <3k users, but once you reach 3k and get the cv privilege, it changes into the custom reason. Maybe we should put the "Blatantly off-topic" reason for everyone, regardless of their rep. http://i.stack.imgur.com/cKjJz.png

Comment: @Lundin "blatantly off-topic" Maybe. Could be abused though. The not about programming custom reason is applied relatively seldom compared to the total number.

Comment: @Trilarion The custom close reason is abused fairly often too. Any close reason can be abused.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As it happens, I have a query for this that I used [prior to the introduction of the 10K tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257449/new-10k-tool-question-close-statistics), which allows generating more or less the same information for an arbitrary date-period.

So...

### Closure statistics for 2016

#### Context

```
Total questions closed 
---------------------- 
358064                 
    
Total questions asked PctClosed 
--------------------- --------- 
3201442               11.18 %
```

#### Close reason usage - numbers

```
Name                                       Closed     Closed->Edited Closed->Reopened Cl->Ed->Re 
------------------------------------------ ---------- -------------- ---------------- ---------- 
duplicate                                      128499      27946           6046             2281 
off-topic - Questions asking us to **recom          5          0              0                0 
off-topic - belongs on another site in the       1848         17             14                2 
off-topic - Questions seeking debugging he      39298       6593           1005              897 
off-topic - was caused by **a problem that       8204        721             72               36 
off-topic                                        1370        234             92               36 
off-topic - Questions on **professional se       3917        157             15                4 
off-topic - Questions about **general comp      10723        495             84               27 
off-topic - Questions asking us to **recom      28878       2975            198              157 
off-topic - Other (add a comment explainin       4700        451             52               24 
primarily opinion-based                         13339       1842            171               87 
too broad                                       66446      11692            897              734 
unclear what you're asking                      50837      11843           1167             1037
```

#### Close reason usage - percentages

```
% of Closed Name                                       Closed->Edited Closed->Reopened Cl->Ed->Re 
----------- ------------------------------------------ -------------- ---------------- ---------- 
 35.9%      duplicate                                   21.7%           4.7%             8.2%     
  0.0%      off-topic - Questions asking us to **recom   0.0%           0.0%                      
  0.5%      off-topic - belongs on another site in the   0.9%           0.8%            11.8%     
 11.0%      off-topic - Questions seeking debugging he  16.8%           2.6%            13.6%     
  2.3%      off-topic - was caused by **a problem that   8.8%           0.9%             5.0%     
  0.4%      off-topic                                   17.1%           6.7%            15.4%     
  1.1%      off-topic - Questions on **professional se   4.0%           0.4%             2.5%     
  3.0%      off-topic - Questions about **general comp   4.6%           0.8%             5.5%     
  8.1%      off-topic - Questions asking us to **recom  10.3%           0.7%             5.3%     
  1.3%      off-topic - Other (add a comment explainin   9.6%           1.1%             5.3%     
  3.7%      primarily opinion-based                     13.8%           1.3%             4.7%     
 18.6%      too broad                                   17.6%           1.3%             6.3%     
 14.2%      unclear what you're asking                  23.3%           2.3%             8.8%
```

#### Top-10 custom close reasons

```
Questions Custom OT Reason (other)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
944       I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
271       Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)                                                          
245       I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
178       I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
162       Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).                                                         
160       I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
145       I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
131       I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
109       I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
109       I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO
```

#### Caveats

- Like [those other numbers I posted today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289797/2016-a-year-in-closing), this counts questions that were *closed* in 2016, not necessarily those that were asked *and* closed in 2016.
- *Unlike* those earlier stats, this makes a half-hearted effort to avoid double-counting questions that get closed or reopened more than once, so some numbers will be slightly lower.
- I wrote this query two years ago and haven't touched it since Oded built the 10K tool, so chances are there are inaccuracies that he fixed and I didn't bother picking up. Percentages should be in the right ballpark though.

Comment: Why is "*off-topic - Questions asking us to \*\*recom*" repeated? What does "*off-topic*" alone mean (clearly it's not the sum of all off-topic reasons)?

Comment: There are/were two variations on that close reason used over the past year, @Oriol. OT alone can mean a few things, but all of them can be lumped into "folks couldn't agree on WHY it was OT".

Comment: So much magento on SO :)

Comment: In the Top 10 custom close reasons there is twice a redirect to super-user, one with and one without a period (numbers 2 and 5), are those the same?

Comment: We may need a "this is not about programming" close reason.

Comment: I'm pretty surprised we had literally only 5 questions asking us for recommendations. Honestly that sounds suspicious to me given our scale

Comment: It's a bit confusing because there were *two* different recommendation close reasons used during the year, @David. One got used on 5 questions; the other on just shy of 29 thousand questions.

Answer (score 7):

The following figures were extracted from the data provided in Shog9's answer in an attempt to get an idea of how often incorrect question closures are identified and corrected.

The metric I'm using is simply questions that are closed then reopened without being edited, with the reasoning being that if a question did not need to be edited in order to be reopened, the closure was incorrect.

```
Name                                    Closed Reopened Clo->No Edit->Reo % of Clo % of Reo
--------------------------------------- ------ -------- ----------------- -------- --------
duplicate                               128499     6046              3765    2.92%   62.27%
off-topic - Questions asking us to **re      5        0                 0    0.00%    0.00%
off-topic - belongs on another site in    1848       14                12    0.65%   85.71%
off-topic - Questions seeking debugging  39298     1005               108    0.27%   10.75%
off-topic - was caused by **a problem t   8204       72                36    0.44%   50.00%
off-topic                                 1370       92                56    4.09%   60.87%
off-topic - Questions on **professional   3917       15                11    0.28%   73.33%
off-topic - Questions about **general c  10723       84                57    0.53%   67.86%
off-topic - Questions asking us to **re  28878      198                41    0.14%   21.58%
off-topic - Other (add a comment explai   4700       52                28    0.60%   53.85%
primarily opinion-based                  13339      171                84    0.63%   49.12%
too broad                                66446      897               163    0.25%   18.17%
unclear what you're asking               50837     1167               130    0.26%   11.14%
TOTALS                                  358064     9813              4184    1.17%   42.64%
```

#### My Conclusions

- 1.17% of all closures in 2016 were identified as incorrect and corrected.
- 42.64% of all reopens in 2016 can be attributed to the question being closed incorrectly

#### Caveats

- The initial close votes on these questions may not have been incorrect when they were cast, as this only counts edits that were submitted after the closure; however, the question would have still been incorrectly closed.
- I'm sure there are many incorrect closures that were either identified and not corrected, or simply not identified; however, this was not intended to identify *all* incorrect closures, only closures that were identified and corrected.
- This may include questions that were reopened incorrectly. To correct this, we would have to eliminate questions that were closed, not edited, reopened, then closed for the same reason, then also eliminate questions that were then reopened without being edited (and on, and on, and on).
- All of the caveats in Shog9's answer.

Comment: I really don't think "correct" and "incorrect" are useful terms in this context. They assume a sort of Platonic ideal of what a constitutes a valid question on SO. I don't believe such a thing exists because people I trust have dramatically differing opinions on what constitutes an answerable question. It seems to me that questions reopened without an edit represent mere differences of opinion rather than any sort of mistake.

Comment: Sure, there may be cases where people just have a difference of opinon. More so for some close reasons than others. However, I do believe that this gives a somewhat accurate representation of incorrect closures that were corrected, or as accurate as can be reasonably expected. I see plenty of questions closed where the close votes were used as super downvotes or the voters were simply misinformed. I'm not directly implying that all of the highlighted questions were deliberately closed when they shouldn't have been, merely erroneously closed.

Comment: For duplicate questions the "incorrectness" of the closure  seems to be highest.

Comment: "Questions asking us to **re" appears twice.

Comment: @lundin that comment has an answer in the comments of Shog9's answer