# What is a reasonable length of time to give for a poor question to be improved before voting to delete?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49593399/73226) was undoubtedly poor and closed 40 minutes after asking. It was then deleted 16 minutes after that.

Thus giving the questioner 16 minutes to act on the advice in the close message

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center,
>   please edit the question.

In my view this is unreasonably short. Am I wrong to think that?

---

**Image of question for < 10K users**

[image]

Comment: Can't the OP undelete their question on their own?

Comment: @yivi - not as far as I am aware. This Q is based on the assumption they can't. If they can then that would change things!

Comment: No, they can't undelete. [But they can edit it and cast an undelete vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344375/1426539).

Comment: Well, taking all things into consideration, and weighing the facts, and having thoroughly investigated the possibilities, it's better to just actually read the rules/tour, instead of clicking 'OK', and ask a good question to start with.

Comment: Yeah, I guess 16 min between closure and deletion is not very long but at the same time they had an infinite amount of time available to read the help center on how to write a question before actually posting it.

Comment: @MartinJames - that would seem to be an argument for auto deleting all questions on closure?

Comment: Also, there are levels of unacceptability.  The featured Q above is terribru for multiple reasons and it's a mercy to euthanize it quickly before too many downvotes accumulate or, worse, some cucumber answers it:(

Comment: @MartinSmith no - some can, and do, get edited or whatever and reopened - fine!  Some, you want to scratch out your eyeballs.

Comment: @MartinJames - I've nothing against quick deletes when the question is unsalvageable. I participated in this one recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588525/urgent-please-help-to-understand-this-code - but this question could have been edited into shape with moving the error message from the image to the question and a summary of the pertinent facts

Comment: @MartinSmith yes - I wish more OP's would do just that.  I am quick to close bad questions, sure, but if I see an edit, code and/or error-message added in, say, then I'm only too happy to re-open vote equally quickly.  Doesn't happen often enough:(

Comment: @MartinSmith 'but this question could have been edited into shape'.. yes, but it did not happen.  Two users answered it before it got closed - obviously, it was not closed quickly enough.

Comment: So your heuristic is if it is (a) unsalvageable (b) has answers then vote to delete ASAP else wait a bit?

Comment: @MartinSmith well, for me, I just make a decision and close-vote or not.  There's not time to manage timeouts:)

Comment: The real question is how a garbage post like that gets past the quality filter and onto the site in the first place. I've seen a fair number like this lately. Why should anyone else have to waste their time even _deciding_ whether it needs to be deleted? A single line of text and a link to an image shouldn't be sufficient to create a post.

Comment: Honestly the delete votes could have been better used elsewhere on content that would not get cleaned up by automatic processes. Sure that means the post is around longer but it will go away and allow other content to be cleaned up with those votes.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's *very* hard to judge quality of a post automatically, particularly when you consider that it's important to have a low false positive rate (especially if you're going to go so far as to prevent the question from being posted entirely; if you take steps to mitigate the problems of false positives, you can afford to have more of them).

Comment: While this is a good question in general, the specific example isn't all that compelling. If you look at the timestamps, you'll note the first comment pointing out the problems with the question was posted quite a bit earlier than 16 minutes, and that between the first warnings and deletion the OP got an answer and wrote a comment to it, without bothering to fix the question.

Comment: I want to see some true negatives in this genre (acceptable questions that are this short) before I start worrying about false positives.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - there are plenty of highly scored questions as short. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/833733/short-questions-high-score though personally I don't want to get into a discussion about the "acceptability" of any of them in the comments here as that would be going off on a tangent

Comment: "bellow" with 2 "l": just close as typo

Comment: @yivi A user can undelete a question they deleted voluntarily. They can't undelete a question deleted by other users; in that case, it needs to receive enough undelete votes.

Comment: On the rare case that I _do_ ask a question on Stack Overflow, I usually spend half an hour or more researching, creating an MVCE, and detailing everything as much as I can.  Then I make sure I spend the next half an hour to an hour refreshing so I can respond immediately to feedback to prevent my question from being downvoted and closed.  I'm not sure if this is the behavior that Stack Overflow encourages, but it's what I have been trained to do by the community.

Comment: I guess it's okay if that's what's expected, but I think that should be very clear in the help section.  Rather than a link at the [bottom of the asking section in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) or a link on the [new question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) that leads to the help center page, the ask question documentation should be required reading for all new users with a bright red warning that their question _will_ be downvoted and closed if they don't adhere to it.  That's the attitude of the community, so that's what should be communicated.

Comment: @MartinJames what do you mean by 'cucumber'? Is that SO lingo for someone who gains rep from answering dumb Qs? Or just a fun diss? I plan to use it either way

Comment: @brandaemon: People who don't take the time to write even one complete sentence, let alone two, aren't going to take any extra time reading the documentation. We can already make that case against uncooperative users without having to make the documentation annoying to read for those who are willing to read and heed it in the first place.

Answer (score 51):

My opinion is that we shouldn't bother with deleting this type of questions. If it's closed, downvoted and has no upvoted answers, it would be [Roomba'd](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) within a few days. If OP improves the question during that time, it would be saved.

Heavily downvoted posts (-4 or less if I remember correctly) would be removed from the home page even without deleting.

Comment: -4 or less is correct: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138382/158100

Comment: @rene or less than -3

Comment: "[...] it would be Roomba'd within a few days" -- This reminds me of [a complaint I once made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337263/2751851).

Comment: The question had an accepted answer, and so couldn't be automatically deleted.

Comment: Thank you. I can't see how deleting a post in under an hour can be reasonable. Especially considering the question was answerable.

Comment: @MikeD. consider giving a read to [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601)

Comment: In order to answer **every** question about programming we shouldn't delete answerable questions in under an hour. Not that I fully agree with the attitude behind that statement anyway, but I'm in the minority there. I see this as a place for people to get help with programming problems and it is structured in a way that is very useful to future visitors. This question wasn't given a chance. But I've been around and around on this already last night and I don't feel like doing it again.

Comment: Deciding to delete non-obvious garbage takes a lot of time already. We shouldn't have to waste time deciding whether to delete obvious garbage, too. If you don't think we should delete Roomba-eligible questions, there should be an immediately available and obvious indicator that the question is Roomba-eligible and when it will be Roombaed.

Comment: @MikeD. SO isn't a site for every possible programming question. It's a knowledge repository for self learning.

Comment: Well, I took the word *every* from the text of the answer that gnat linked to.

Comment: @MikeD. the bad quality content shouldn't even exist. Nobody should be subject of such torture such as investing 1 second of their time reading bad quality content. The faster you get rid of bad quality content the more happy is the general populace.

Comment: @jpmc26: What is "non-obvious garbage"? Generally the word garbage is used to refer to material that is obviously, and egregiously, bad. If you're spending time deciding whether or not something is garbage, it probably isn't and you probably shouldn't be wasting any more of your time trying to treat it as such.

Comment: @MikeD. "I see this as a place for people to get help with programming problems..." This is a good read for you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1394393. SO is a help site, but it's it's a volunteer site that seeks to keep its answerers interested. To that end, it doesn't want to frustrate its answerers with low effort questions. If 90% of the questions you read were as bad as this one was, would you want to keep posting answers? Would you feel like you're helping, or just like you're spoonfeeding? I guarantee you the more questions you see, the more you'll get tired of low effort.

Comment: @BoltClock I guess you have me there. My point is that questions take time to evaluate, and I do my darnedest to make sure I evaluate something closely before I go casting votes of any kind on it. I don't like being told that I should be spending even *more* time on that evaluation, so if information like that should be considered, it should be more readily available. (That said, I've seen plenty of garbage questions that most people didn't even notice were garbage. They're often doing some kind of list processing but leave out several key details that would invalidate several approaches.)

Comment: @BoltClock If we don't delete content in under an hour will 90% of the site turn into bad questions? I don't think so. So what does that have to do with this question? No one said to leave it forever in its original state.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for pointing me to another answer that makes me feel excluded from the site. I'm glad I already feel appropriately about asking questions here, in that I try to avoid ever doing it. I didn't realize that was actually a good thing but here we are. SO is a Q&A website where **we do not want your questions. Go away!** I don't even understand why we allow new users to sign up...

Comment: @jpmc26 I've been active on this site for over 8 years, I've seen plenty of questions. Just because I don't have 10k rep doesn't mean that I don't know what I'm talking about. **Big thanks to whoever deleted these comments before. I'd REALLY love to know why.**

Comment: Geeze, I do feel a bit silly having tagged @BoltClock incorrectly above though...

Comment: @MikeD. Did I mention your reputation? No. Did I mention how long you've been here? No. I linked an answer that I thought would help you understand a different but widely held perspective. I feel excluded from this site every day. Because I don't know enough, I'm not fast enough, I'm not smart enough, and I often pass on questions I don't think are well put together. But that doesn't matter. What matters is that I post something helpful every now and then. My point is that it's a good thing when this site comes down hard on low effort posts. Those kinds of posts *should* be unwelcome.

Comment: I was responding to your comment of *I guarantee you the more questions you see, the more you'll get tired of low effort.* which implied that I had not yet seen enough questions to form a relevant opinion. A counter to that would be that I have actually seen a lot of questions in my 8 years here. I completely disagree that it's a good thing that the site comes down so hard on potentially useful questions.

Comment: And I'm not referring to not feeling smart enough or anything like that. I know I'm not the smartest person here or the best programmer. I'm referring to the feeling that I should avoid posting anything at all because should I make a mistake it will end up with people acting like this about it.

Answer (score 15):

## Specific Example

The action taken on the question was reasonable. Here's how I know:

- Question posted at 2018-03-31 23:23:42Z (T = 0 minutes).
- Requests for improvement were made at 2018-03-31 23:26:08Z and 2018-03-31 23:26:13Z. (T = 3 min).
- Answer posted at 2018-03-31 23:29:44Z (T = 6 min).
- Comment posted **by the asker** at 2018-03-31 23:43:12Z (T = 20 min). [image: screenshot of asker comment with timestamp]
- Second answer posted at 2018-03-31 23:44:21Z (T = 21 min).
- Asker commented *again* at 2018-03-31 23:57:25Z (T = 34 min).
- Question is closed at 2018-04-01 00:03:28Z (T = 40 min).
- Answerer comment at 2018-04-01 00:08:43Z (T = 45 min)
- Asker commented for the *third time* at 2018-04-01 00:14:01Z (T = 51 min), saying, "Thanks, now it work [sic]."
- Question is deleted at 2018-04-01 00:19:15Z (T = 56 min)

(All T-values are calculated using only the minutes. There may be some slight errors if you account for the seconds.)

The user was given ample opportunity to improve their question, refused to do so, and the question was rightly deleted as a result. Any question of "reasonable amount of time" is negated by the fact they clearly saw responses to their question.

Unfortunately, this low effort user *also* got answers and ended up solving their problem, which is clearly all they cared about. This means they were rewarded for essentially vandalizing the site, so they will likely happily do so again next time they have a problem and want someone to solve it for them.

### General Question

If you want to have this discussion, find an example of a user who actually cared about the quality of their question and it was deleted before they could fix it.

Also note that such users have several options at their disposal in the rare case they're actually affected negatively by a quick deletion:

- Post a new, improved question.
- Post on Meta asking for help with improving the question. This is a particularly good idea if the asker doesn't know what to improve or if they're under a question ban, as Meta regulars are able to give suggestions and help with undeletion if needed. Although posting a new question is probably the better course of action if it was bad enough to be heavily downvoted and quickly deleted.
- If they can't post on Meta and can't post an improved question and still want to improve their question, flag for moderator help. I'm not sure what a moderator would do exactly, but possibly they could post a Meta question on behalf of the user. If they can spend the time, they could potentially work with the user on improvements and then undelete the question so they could edit it. But I'm fairly certain this is *exceedingly* rare.

Comment: I wonder if this kind of question is the exception which proves the rule.  I've seen *most* questions go this way in which the OP is actively engaging and yet refuses to improve their question.  I've seen a *handful* of questions in which the OP *tries* to engage.  I've seen a similarly-sized handful of questions in which the OP *hasn't* engaged.  In just about ***all*** of those questions I've seen the same thing happen - close and delete expeditiously.

Comment: @Makoto I've seen questions where the OP simply ignore any request and the question is deleted by the abandoned not closed rule... many of them... they are all in https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days recently deleted.

Comment: @Makoto I've expanded my bit about making a Meta post in response to your comment. I'm not 100% whether you're agreeing with me or disagreeing, but I think the bottom line is that if an asker can't get their question in a passable state before it gets deleted, then heading to Meta is the best way to handle it. A user who is actively engaging in trying to improve their question is likely to be well received, and I suspect that Meta regulars would be willing to help with whatever needs to be done once advice has been given. (Posting a new one is probably the better choice when possible.)

Answer (score 7):

Well... the particular question is complete trash. Not only does the OP fail to understand how SO works, they fail to understand how human communication works. Therefore it is pretty safe to say that the question is completely unsalvageable.

The correct way to deal with this "by the book" is to close it, down-vote it to oblivion and leave it there, in case the OP improves their human-to-human communication during the period when the question is on-hold. Eventually it will get status closed, and then after a while longer, it will get automatically deleted by the trusty Roomba bot.

However, veteran users tend to get bitter at the flood of trash like this, and throw in their delete votes as well - they just want the obvious trash to be deleted from the site. The origin of this is frustration from veteran users, when they notice that the quality of the site is in steady decline. Despite endless meta discussions and live experiments about how to improve quality of questions.

In those cases, we'll just have to side with the veterans and let them vent a bit by deleting the post from existence, even though this is strictly speaking not the correct way to moderate the site.

But since we want to keep the veterans with excellent technical knowledge, who know how the site works, we'll just have to cope with it. To delete a post you need 3 users with >20k rep. The price for this is that we might lose the occasional author of poorly-written questions.

Comment: Given that the ability to vote to delete questions with enough downvotes immediately after they're closed is a 20k privilege, I'm pretty sure speedily deleting questions that 1) are this bad, and, perhaps more importantly, 2) the asker simply has no intention of improving after the fact, isn't "not the correct way to moderate the site", but an intended use of the privilege.

Comment: "The fastest way to kill any Q&A site is to flood it with low-quality questions... We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to **maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers**. If this means aggressively downvoting or closing unworthy and uninteresting questions, so be it..." ([Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/))

Comment: *molluscoid lifeform user* really?

Comment: Aren't you full of yourself.. if that's the way "higher life forms" communicate, I don't think everyone wants to join you there, mate..

Comment: @StackingForHeap Did you read the question that triggered this discussion? "In the code below I have an error. Please help. Screenshot of error" (No code posted.) It's rather the people who post such crap and waste everyone elses time that are full of themselves - I find it very rude and so I am rude in return.

Comment: Well, I guess you can just insult them then. That sure is "being nice" but then they aren't really people to you. They're *invertebrate sea animals* so who cares?

Comment: I think root cause for rudeness in cases like that is a [system failure to maintain quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281807/165773), "negative feelings (and their respective terms) may simply indicate that a community lacks power and tools to protect itself from inappropriate content..."

Comment: @BoltClock:  I agree in principle, but you see antipatterns occur frequently.  It then underscores the question of improving the *automated* deletion scripts so that garbage that a 20K+ user would normally delete would be deleted faster instead of leaving it solely to them, or to have the question fester and potentially become ineligible for deletion.

Comment: @Mike D.: The mental image of Lundin debating an octopus is quite hard to ignore now. It's also an invertebrate sea animal, but also one of the most intelligent.

Comment: @gnat I guess that excuses it then. We should amend the "be nice" rule to "Rudeness and belittling language are not okay unless you are a high rep user and judge them to stupid." Sounds like we should just get rid of the "Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions." too. "Don't be a jerk." += "unless you're a high rep user."

Comment: **Be patient** but delete questions in under an hour because that's a good thing. LOL.... *sigh*

Comment: @MikeD. have you read the link referred in prior comment? Rudenes is not ignored. It is penalized rather heavily but somehow this doesn't work, "how come that after years of plugging users' mouths and twisting their arms with _summers of love_ and _hunting the snark_, the second-highest-voted question at MSO is [Why is Stack Overflow so **negative** of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/839601) Makes one wonder if this way works, doesn't it..."

Comment: Yeah, i'm not in your "core group" I guess. These new people aren't either and no one is interested in allowing them to be. You seem to think that by allowing more people to close questions the high rep users will be nicer because they are less burnt out from handling them. Maybe that is the case for some people. But I've seen a lot more just elitist attitudes that aren't going to be fixed because someone else is dealing with it. They WANT to deal with it and they clearly think of the others as lower lifeforms. There are whole groups of people laser focused on deleting q's as fast as possible.

Comment: @MikeD. Well, you should obviously not leave such comments after you close/downvote/delete. Any comment there needs to be polite and constructive, and if one isn't able to write such a comment, best to not write one at all. That's the key of moderating SO, you have to learn how to just cast your votes and leave, no matter how horrible the question is. Anyway, rudeness is not the topic here, but rather why this post was deleted so quickly in the first place.

Comment: More interesting is the highest voted answer to the "What is Stack Overflow's Goal?" question talks about the exact thing I'm still complaining about now. * SO users were afraid to ask questions, worried that not getting their ducks in a row before asking would get them responses that were intended to chase them away.* Maybe the mean comments have lessened but the use of the structural tools available to rid the site of these questions remains as does the attitude. The next answer is just the same old **we're not here to help people** elitism that I've already said I'm sick of. *shrug*

Comment: @BoltClock I do have some experience of struggling with a lot of ARMs in my everyday work... though not of the inkapable kind.

Comment: @Lundin coming from the person who had no problems insulting users in their answer that doesn't hold a lot of weight.

Comment: @MikeD. Indeed we are not here to help people with 1) how to communicate with other humans, nor 2) how to write a question in English that others can understand, nor are we really here to teach people 3) how to post a MCVE so that the problem can be reproduced and the question can actually be answered by humans - who can't read minds. Summary: this site's purpose is not to teach communication or common sense. We are here to answer technical programming problems. For free.

Comment: *sigh* whatever makes you feel better about yourself. i'll go back with the other mollusks.

Comment: @MikeD. Yeah when you run out of counter-arguments you can always sigh. Thanks for your valuable input.

Comment: I'm not out of counter-arguments I've just said them all already and I'm tired of repeating myself.

Comment: We have a fundamental disagreement on what the purpose of this website is. All of this obsession with ridding the site of "inferior" content is actually what will kill it in the end. Or it'll just become the same old people always here with very little fresh blood. So, in summary. Deleting questions in minutes is a good thing. We don't care about how this affects anyone but high rep answers (who like it) because helping people is really beside the point. So really, they should hire people to come up with good college-level questions that the high-rep "professionals" can answer for fun and fame

Comment: They'd probably have to charge you something at that point but wouldn't it be worth it to never ever see a question you didn't like?

Comment: @MikeD. It is not for you and me to decide what kind of questions that should be asked here. It is already decided here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. The site is for helping others _with their programming problems_. SO does not require any particular level of programming knowledge (any longer) in order to post. We do not however help with how to learn English, how to communicate, how to cure your headache, how to fix your car or how to do tap-dancing. There may or may not be other Stack Exchange sites for that. This is not the place to ask for "general help".

Comment: Looking past some broken English shouldn't be a problem on the global internet. Helping people to communicate on SO would be nice and I imagine part of **Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions.** but to me it seems like the general attitude is that line doesn't mean anything. The question here was not about headaches or tap dancing or any of that spurious garbage you've thrown out. It was a programming question with an error message posted in a way that wasn't ideal. It was answerable.

Comment: But go ahead and keep bringing up that same straw-man of "horrible completely off-topic question" that no one is actually talking about here.

Comment: @MikeD. This particular case falls into "in order to answer this, we first have to teach you how to communicate". Which this site isn't about. Regarding assuming good intentions, you should have been around here long enough to know that this is very often not the case.There's countless amounts of people who post just to have an answer to their homework problem. They don't care about the quality of the question, about the site policies or even about programming. We get _hundreds_ of such questions every day, where the OP clearly does not have any good intentions, but 100% egocentric intentions.

Comment: Yep, that's why it had answers because before you could answer it you had to spend a week in the Himalayas teaching the poster about the Zen art of SO question asking. And of course you're right to ignore the part of the rule you don't want to follow because it isn't true? OK. Continue to rationalize your bad behavior because you're so much better than everyone else.

Comment: Given some more time  this question would have been edited into better shape and answered. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365412/how-to-prevent-a-poorly-worded-question-that-im-working-to-answer-from-being-de But who cares about any of that? YOU might have to see a bad question and that is enough of a reason to nuke anything you deem sub-par on sight. You can be rude and impatient and assume bad intentions and somehow still feel like you're doing the right thing. The OP of the other meta question had their time wasted and content was lost but that isn't as important as you are.

Comment: @MikeD. What's your basis for asserting that the question would have been edited into shape if it wasn't deleted?  There are many thousands of bad posts posted every day.  Only a few percent ever get edited into shape, and for posts *this* bad the odds drops considerably.

Comment: @Servy Did you click the link in my previous comment that went to a question you were already active in where the OP said they were going to edit  the question? Or are you being intentionally obtuse?

Comment: @MikeD. I presume everyone should read  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296609/792066 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341547/792066

Comment: A bunch of numbers? I don't get it. Why does that mean that questions should be deleted as fast as possible? Why does that mean a question that has answers shouldn't be given a chance?

Comment: @Mike D.: The site would be far less productive if we tried investing all our limited resources into giving every question a chance. Questions being given a chance would only help the asker asking it and be a waste of time for everyone else because nobody else would understand their questions. And that's assuming we manage to help the asker at all, which isn't always the case even if we do try. I'm sure you've had times you've been frustrated trying to help because the other person just doesn't seem to know how to communicate their needs, says things they don't mean, moves goalposts, etc.

Comment: @Mike D.: We can't be everything to everybody. Nobody is perfect. Neither the asker, nor the answerer. Expecting either side to be perfect to the other is untenable. Expecting a reasonable level of cooperation and competence from both parties simultaneously on the other hand, not such a big ask IMHO.

Comment: Again, I just don't see that the response to this question was reasonable. (Also I never said EVERY question but FFS.... anyway.) Next, the attitude that people have towards these posts and the people that make them really rubs me the wrong way. But again, the community is fine with that too. I just don't understand it. Not that it's a new phenomenon. I just don't like it. But that probably also factors into why i am defending this particular incident so much.

Answer (score 5):

One very good reason for deleting such questions quickly is that the OP seldom stops with one garbage question.  Deleting the post quickly helps stop overall site damage by getting the user [that much closer to a question-ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/148310).

Comment: The user is no closer to the question ban with the post deleted than with the post undeleted.  In fact, with the post undeleted it can attract further downvotes, moving them closer to being quesotin banned.  Deleting it prevents that.

Comment: @Servy, [deleted questions count towards the ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/148310): **"Additionally, deletion itself counts against questions if less than 30 days old when deleted if others have invested time into answering or moderating the question."**

Comment: @Servy, where does it say that *additional* downvotes count towards the ban?

Comment: @BrockAdams Looking at the link, that appears to be talking about self-deleting questions that have been answered, not necessarily other users deleting a question.

Comment: @BrockAdams "it is partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities" how they're weighted, specifically, is kept secret, but it's clear that they are a factor.  Additionally there's my own anecdotal evidence of looking over the profiles of lots of people complaining about their posts bans, which leads me to pretty confidently say that the number of downvotes on their posts is a factor.

Comment: @AndrewMyers, read it again.  Esp: "But if a large percentage of your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they are not suitable for the site. Posting them consumes time from users who read them, edit them, or respond to them. **Therefore deleted posts have an effect on the filter, among many other factors.**".

Comment: @Servy, I see you restating it, but I don't see a reference.  Unlike deleted posts (which would be *much* more severe anyway) which ARE documented to have an effect.  Please *document* your claim or reverse your downvote.

Comment: @BrockAdams I provided a quote.  The post even repeats the same line, multiple times.  If you honestly think post score isn't factored into the post ban then you apparently have very little experience with it.

Comment: The same page you cited.

Comment: @Servy, thanks.  But your *conjecture* is that somehow downvotes (a dime a dozen and low real consequence) are weighted more heavily than deletion!?!  (Which is orders of magnitude more rare and orders of magnitude more severe.)

Comment: @BrockAdams All anyone can ever do is conjecture on the topic.  The specifics of the weighting are specifically kept secret, so the only people who aren't guessing aren't allowed to speak about it publicly.  Why is your conjecture of consequence and mine is not?  But, as I've said, I've spent a lot of time following meta and looking over posts of people asking about their post ban, and talking with SE users speaking (admittedly vaguely) about the system, and what I've seen indicates that posts' score is a very significant factor.  But yes, I don't have facts on how exactly the two compare.

Comment: YAY!!! Banning people we find inferior as quickly as possible!! Hurray!!!! I love the attitude around here it is so **patient**, and **welcoming**, and **assuming of good intentions**. /s

Comment: @MikeD. Intentions isn't really relevant here.  What matters is results.  If someone is trying to ask a good question, but simply can't do it, at the end of the day they still can't ask a good question.  That said, a question like the example here *is* a very strong indication that they're making no attempt whatsoever to ask a good question, so we don't really need to make much in the way of assumptions.  Their question makes it very clear how little they care about asking a good question.

Comment: Yeah, we'll just disagree on that point.

Comment: @MikeD. Which point?  Do you think that we should encourage people to post bad content as long as they want to post good content, or do you feel that that user made an honest attempt to ask a quality, on topic, useful question, and simply failed to do so?  Or both?

Comment: We disagree that the content was so utterly awful that it didn't deserve a chance. Or that less than an hour is a reasonable chance for a question that could have been improved.

Comment: I don't know how many times I have to say that only to have people twist my words into "All bad posts should be allowed forever! Let people ask about the smell of their dog's farts!" Which was not ever my point.

Comment: Well I didn't make that point in that comment (I've made it in other ones on other posts, so I don't have a problem with you claiming I said it).  The two points in that comment are, again, that intentions don't matter, results do, but that the post demonstrates that the author didn't demonstrate an intention to write a good question regardless.

Comment: OP seldom stops with one garbage question? [[citation needed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364734/1079354)]

Comment: @Makoto, That post flat out states that he has no evidence of *deleted* question askers improving over time: "I have not yet answered your question which would require me to break out users by whether they have shown the ability to ask well-received questions over time."  It rather makes my point with the huge percentage of users with a negative asking record.  Although it is true that "many of our questions are asked by people who never ask a second question" (as it should be).  ... Furthermore Jon's post undercuts Servy's silly notion that downvotes somehow outweigh deletion.

Comment: Why would deleted posts improve over time? If I was a new user and my post got deleted in under an hour I'd just give up and leave. (Which most people are adamantly fine with.) So that's not really a meaningful metric.

Answer (score -6):

I agree with many comments. The number of new questions we get daily is so huge nowadays that we should "educate" the newcomers better, to save time and energy for actual answers. This means the newcomers should take a bit more time to learn to make a proper question, and questions that are just crap, should be taken "offline" so long as they're fixed or cleaned away from the system for good.

Personally I think the best would be just to hide the question from all the others but the OP, and give them reasonable amount of time (more than 16 minutes for sure) to fix the question. Maybe allow a system where a question flagged or downvoted is shown to people who downvoted it, and if they flag it as "ok-to-go", it will be reposted.

*This is because sometimes question deemed as "bad" is bad, even if it somewhat complies with the guides here, and the OP might just need some input from the other users how to clear his question or what data to add to help..*

Comment: "hide the question from all the others but the OP" -- as far as I understand that's just what deletion do

Comment: @gnat Yes, was just pointing that there should be enough time for the posters to react - and maybe a system where it can be approved by the same people who flagged it.

Comment: The question at issue had two comments _within 3 minutes of posting_ with suggestions for improvement; they were ignored. Moreover, closure doesn't prevent the OP from fixing the question. Not even deletion prevents that (although it makes it harder to get the question visible again).

Comment: The OP had a few minutes short of an hour to fix their question, not just 15 minutes.  (Not to mention the plethora of resources helping them to ask an appropriate question *before they've even asked it.)  The OP had more than enough opportunity to ask a good question if they were actually willing to do so.