# Why was my rude/abusive flag declined?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I was just looking through my flags and I noticed that my rude/abusive flag for this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365506/8953824) was declined. I am wondering why? Not only is the answer rude about an OP but the answer's author admitted he was being rude in the comments below. Some of the comments on the answer are also rather rude but the one that I marked as such was disputed but that's not as strange to me as the declined flag.

Here is the author's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365467/what-is-a-reasonable-length-of-time-to-give-for-a-poor-question-to-be-improved-b/365506#comment570675_365506):

> @StackingForHeap Did you read the question that triggered this discussion? "In the code below I have an error. Please help. Screenshot of error" (No code posted.) It's rather the people who post such crap and waste everyone elses time that are full of themselves - I find it very rude and **so I am rude in return.**

Comment: Comments [archived](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/172772/discussion-on-question-by-icec-why-was-my-rude-abusive-flag-declined). I've pinged the moderator responsible, but of course anyone is free to write an answer with their own opinion on the situation. But 40-some comments is a bit much for a straightforward question.

Comment: Thank you @Shog9 I agree that was getting long and pointless. I have just seen "less offensive" comments on here and other stack sites be deleted for rudeness so I was just trying to understand what makes this one different.

Comment: to ask is allowed to answer is courtesy . . . you did well anyway to ask this question @IceC

Comment: One thing that might have contributed to declining the flag is that moderators don't see the entire revision history (as far as I know) so maybe they saw the edited version.

Comment: @IceC We all stopped commenting because Shog9 here archived the comments. If you wish to continue the discussion please do it in the chatroom, or accept that not only you has the right to continue, and we're bound to get everything moved again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I handled that flag. I'll first note that I disputed the answer flag, I didn't decline it. The flag doesn't count against you in that case, it just isn't marked as helpful. It's like the flag didn't exist to begin with.

I commonly will dispute offensive flags on posts where an edit can bring them back into shape, where the fundamental content itself isn't intended to attack or demean another. This is complicated by the fact that the post is on Meta, a site designed specifically to let people speak their mind about policies and specific posts. A moderator deleting an upvoted opinion can lead to cries of censorship, so I'd like to avoid that if I can.

In this case, I disputed the flag and then attempted to edit the answer to preserve the core sentiment while taking the edge off some of the language. Maybe I didn't go far enough with my edit, but I was worried about changing too much of the tone of the post.

I also declined the comment flag because to delete it would have made much of the surrounding conversation confusing. The comment itself wasn't abusive, it was them explaining why they tended to be rude to people. Again, we provide a little more leeway on comments on Meta than on the main site. It's sometimes useful for people to have a place to vent.

I do recognize what you found objectionable in the original post, and I did think it went a little too far. That's why I didn't decline your flag and tried to edit the post into shape. We're very conservative about accepting spam and offensive flags on posts, because of the negative consequences from them and their use in audits.

Comment: Ahh so I must have gotten my flags backwards then. I thought the answer flag was the declined one since I can't see which flag was which on my end.. I appreciate your input and I can understand and appreciate your reasoning. Thank you for clearing things up!

Comment: @IceC - I'll also note that I disagree with some of the sentiment expressed there (I do not believe people get a free pass to be rude to question askers just because they asked a terrible question), but I can't delete things just because I disagree with them. It's important to give people a place to state things like this, if only to be able to counter them with your own arguments. Moderating Meta content can be very different than dealing with the same on the main site.

Comment: I can understand that. I will be sure to take your aspect of things into consideration from now on

Answer (score 8):

If this was a comment on the main site, I'd 100% have agreed.

But this isn't the main site. This is meta, and things are a bit different. You are allowed to voice your opinion, no matter how unpopular. Granted, some artifacts of that user's answer and comment could've been worded a bit more tastefully, I don't think deletion is the right move here.

Both the answer and the comments represent an opposing point of view, and I think that is valuable to the discussion at hand. I find myself in complete agreement with what was said, even if I don't approve of how it was said. Deleting would effectively censor that opinion and make the discussion hard to follow.

Comment: Would your opinion change if the OP was someone more active to the site and had seen the meta post and that answer? Just curious... either way +1

Comment: @IceC I suspect part of the user's frustration arose from the fact that the user was new. You seldom find active users posting content as poor as this, because they're  either 1) dealt with very quickly, or 2) by being active, have come to understand the culture of the site and the standards expected of them.

Comment: @IceC but to answer your question, if the user was active with a good track record of good questions and answers, then yes, a comment this abrasive would've shocked me quite badly.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2):

I can't decline flags, but I wish that such posts do not become considered "offensive" or "rude".

I understand there is gripe with the use of the word "trash" and with the questioning of the OP's communication skills.

From the answer (emphasis mine):

> Well... the particular **question** is complete trash.

People are not their opinions, nor are they their posts. Some people seem to think that downvoting a post is rude, possibly because they consider that someone is entitled to every thought they have, and every piece of content they generate.

I posit that saying that a post is trash, is fundamentally different than saying that a *person* is trash, and as such, declining the flag was the right action, because the post is definitely not rude or abusive to the person that posted the question that was considered trash.

Discussing ideas and not people is literally basic philosophy class' content, and is objectively considered a good way to evolve in life. This is what "don't take things personal" means.

Comment: Do you have an argument for the statement about OP failing basic human communication? Not trying to be belligerent just trying to understand.

Comment: It's not completely baked, so I left it out for now.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier you know... I would see you as a moderator!  I think that as you say:  `I posit that saying that a post is trash, is fundamentally different than saying that a person is trash`  ! so +1 is guaranteed... even if I am of the opinion that we must be careful how ours words are used

Comment: @ErgotCoslin Hah! I'm way too hot blooded to be moderator, but I appreciate the sentiment :)