# Is this answer insulting the developer who wrote a piece of code really ok?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-answer, code-of-conduct

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64993915/what-does-join-mean-in-javascript/64993999#64993999):

> Its an abomination that works. So you are correct in assuming that when you do a join function call. You pass a empty string so that there is nothing put in between the resulting string.
>
> In javascript you can declare strings with "quotes", 'apostrophes', and `template literals`.
>
> The dev that wrote that line of code thought he was being a cool smart intellectual by skipping the opening and closing parentheses when in reality he just made his code more confusing for everyone else.

as rude or abusive, but it was rejected with the standard "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it."

According to the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), personal attacks are not acceptable, which I felt the last paragraph clearly was, and when another user tried to edit that part out the OP edited it back in so I thought flagging for a moderator was the only reasonable option (interestingly, the comments calling out the OP for doing that *were* deleted at some point after I flagged it).

Am I wrong here? Is this an acceptable answer in its current state?

Comment: It's somewhat unnecessarily abrasive, but it's not wrong or delete-worthy. The answer is opinionated, and it's not insulting a different Stack Overflow user, but it's judging code as being horribly confusing for no good reason - which is a reasonable judgement for answerers to make here on SO.

Comment: @CertainPerformance If it were just attacking the code, that would have been one thing, but it also attacked the developer's motives. Or does it not count if they aren't a SO user?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery - Who said the author of the question and the code was one in the same?

Comment: FWIW, I flagged it too. And edited it, although that got rolled back by the OP.

Comment: @SecurityHound Not me, I think you may have misread my comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flags are declined because an edit was made afterwards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391869/flags-are-declined-because-an-edit-was-made-afterwards)

Comment: @Tom Not really. Again, there was already an edit rolled back on the answer so that wasn't a realistic option.

Comment: I frequently comment '"stop writing 'clever' code".  Since such code makes debugging avoidably difficult, and results in such code being avoidably posted to SO, I really don't care if the OP's take offense, after all, they posted offensive code first:)

Comment: I see nothing insulting about it. The points were valid (even if opinionated). and the term "clever" was a tongue-in-cheek dysphemism pointing to nature of the code. If anything it was factual, I am sure the original author of the code did think they were cleaver. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369208

Answer (score 17):

"Rude or abusive" flags mean that the answer is unsalvageable and should be nuked by a moderator. That one isn't; it conveys useful information that is relevant to the question that was asked. If you feel the tone should be moderated, you can (and should) edit it. If you feel that your well-meaning edits would be rejected by the user, then you should raise a custom flag to call a moderator's attention specifically to the history.

Even upon careful review, I do not think that this answer is rude in such a way that violates our Code of Conduct. It is common practice in code reviews to tell the original author that their code is "too clever" and thus unintentionally obfuscating. This is not an insult against the original developer. Criticizing *code* is OK.

A previous edit was rolled back, which I agree is a bad sign, but (assuming good faith) that might be because the edit removed too much from the answer, moving too far away from the author's intent. I've made another edit that moderates the tone *slightly*, without moving too far away from the author's intent. I've also addressed the gendered language (assuming that the original developer was male), and improved some of the grammar. Hopefully that will be sufficient to address the concerns of all parties.

If you think the answer is wrong (e.g., because the code under question is *not* "too clever", that it serves a legitimate purpose, as shown by the other answers to the question), then that is a downvote reason, not a flag reason.

Comment: As I said in my question, it had already been edited once and the OP rolled it back.

Comment: Yeah. Frankly, I don't see this as rude, even in its current form. I would have also declined a rude/abusive flag on it.

Comment: You really think that's something that's appropriate to include in a SO answer?

Comment: Why not? "The developer who wrote this code was clearly trying to be clever, but it resulted in code that is just confusing." What's insulting about that? That's par for the course in a code review: "you're being too clever here". Do you mean the assumption that the developer is male? I fixed that. You could have, too.

Comment: How do they even know the developer was just trying to be clever? As the other answers even show, there's perfectly valid reasons for doing it that way. Not to mention there's a significant difference in tone between what they wrote and your version. And again, they already rolled back one edit so I had no reason to think they wouldn't do the same for mine too.

Comment: I don't see much difference in tone. It isn't insulting to tell someone that they've tried to be too clever. Arguing that other answers show there's a valid reason to do it is just arguing that the answer is *wrong*, which is a downvote reason, not a flag reason.

Comment: There's a huge difference in tone between "thought he was being a cool smart intellectual" and "thought they were being clever." I suppose we'll just have to disagree on that one.

Comment: I wish more people would call *me* "a cool smart intellectual". :-)

Comment: Even if they're obviously being sarcastic?

Comment: With respect, I'm not sure how the word "abomination" in particular lines up with, and I'm cribbing from the rude or abusive flag text, "civil discourse".

Comment: There's nothing uncivil about referring to an inanimate object as an "abomination".

Comment: @CodyGray there are two ways to play this. First is to say that anything that a reasonable person might find offensive is out. Second is to say that only something that is so offensive that no reasonable person could possibly take it as anything else is out. Which is it? Because I really don't care one way or another as long as it's consistent. The tone and snark in that answer adds zero informational content, and the user who wrote it refused to edit it out, rolled back my edit that edited it out, and then *revenge downvoted three of my answers*. Not a pretty picture.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm not going to get into a debate over the definition of "reasonable". I don't know what point you're trying to establish. I already made the answer as clear as I can possibly make it. Note that no one is telling you that you aren't allowed to raise flags when you want a moderator to take a look. That is what flags are for. If you don't think the answer adds anything to the discussion, downvote it. But don't make accusations about who downvoted your posts. You have absolutely no way of knowing who votes in what way.

Comment: @CodyGray *""Rude or abusive" flags mean that the answer is unsalvageable and should be nuked by a moderator."* So no matter *how* abusive or rude an answer is, as long as it can be edited out, flagging is not an option? I kind of feel that you are describing the purpose of the *Very Low Quality* flag.

Comment: @CodyGray three of my old answers were downvoted right after that exchange, and 24 hours later I got the ol' "serial voting reversed" message. If I'm wrong, that individual has my sincere apologies. As far as the back and forth on your answer here goes, I'm sorry. Rereading what I wrote it seems more like I was trying to incite rather than merely argue the point.

Comment: @JaredSmith Well, the system worked, didn't it? :-) Less flippantly: even if you were right about who was involved in the serial downvoting *this time*, you won't necessarily be right in your assumptions next time, and making these assumptions just creates more problems, so please don't. If not fixed automatically within 24 hours, raise a moderator flag, and we'll handle the revenge downvoting. Custom flags are useful because you can explain more of the context. No need to apologize for anything. Nothing you said upset me. I just disagree with your assessment of the answer.